# Create colour with given lightness value

Tags: color

**How can I create a colour of my chosen hue with a given fixed lightness level?**

For example, how can I create a reddish colour, `col`, so that `ColorConvert[col, "GrayScale"]` will return precisely `GrayLevel[0.6]`?

Does Mathematica have something built-in to assist in this, or do I need to read up on how colours are converted between various representations?  Note that the `b` value in `Hue[h, s, b]` does not correspond to the `GrayLevel` value.  I need to have precise control over what certain colours I use will look like when converted to greyscale.

Comment: "...do I need to read up on how colours are converted between various representations?" - this one, I think. Converting RGB and HSB colors to grayscale isn't too straightforward.

Comment: You might be interested in [this research](http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~leojia/projects/color2gray/index.html).

Comment: @Silvia Can you explain how the specific research paper is improving the contrast in Mathematica's default conversion to gray from its default colormap?

Comment: @Masi Good question. I compared the `ImageHistogram` of [their result](http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~leojia/projects/color2gray/imgs/23_our.png) with that of Mathematica 11's result given by `ColorConvert[theColorPNG,"Grayscale"]`, [they look quite the same](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EG2JA.png). I'm not an expert in related field, but I guess Mathematica is already powered by similar algorithm.

Comment: @Silvia Is Mathematica's result the lower histogram? - - Actually, there are quite big differences between those two approaches. Amplitudes of individual peaks are different, and also the peak locations.

Comment: @Masi I don't remember which is which :( But when I said "quite the same", I meant to say they are similar to each other comparing with the histogram of brightness/illumination channel results from color spaces like XYZ, LAB, etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Conversion Formula

`ColorConvert` uses the following formula for `"Grayscale"` conversion:

$ \mathrm{Grayscale} = 0.299 R + 0.587 G + 0.114 B$

where $R$, $G$, and $B$ are normalized.

### Interactive Example

The following manipulate example will help you finding (and confirming) the conversion based on a fixed $\mathrm{Grayscale}$  and $R$ values.

```
f[g_, gs_, r_] := (gs - .299 r - .587 g)/.114;

Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Show[
    Graphics[{Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}},
       VertexColors -> {RGBColor[r, 0, 0], RGBColor[r, 1, 0], 
         RGBColor[r, 1, 1], RGBColor[r, 0, 1]}]},
     PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
     AspectRatio -> 1,
     ImageSize -> 400,
     Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Green", "Blue"},
     LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 14}],
    Plot[f[g, gs, r], {g, 0, 1}],
    Graphics[{
      Locator[
       Dynamic[pt, (With[{b = f[#[[1]], gs, r]}, 
           If[0 <= b <= 1, pt = {#1[[1]], b}, {.5, .5}]]) &]]
      }]
    ],
   "",
   Row[{"ColorConvert[RGBColor[", Prepend[pt, r], 
     ",\"Grayscale\"]==\n", 
     ColorConvert[RGBColor[Prepend[pt, r]], "Grayscale"]}]
   }],
 {{pt, {.5, .5}}, ControlType -> None},
 {{gs, .5, "Grayscale"}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{r, 1, "Red"}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image: grayscale]

The blue line indicates the colors which has the exact grayscale value. If you move the locator, it tries to snap in to the line and show you RGB value as well as converted graysale value (which should be the same as the slider value).

### Discussion

**belisarius** asked, "Then what is the yellowest color whose grayscale value is .3?".

There are several problems. First, what is "yellow"-ish colors? Are these colors close to {1,1,0} in RGB space? Then the solution is the point on the plane 0.299 x + 0.587 y + 0.114 z = 0.3 whose distance is the shortest from {1,1,0} which can be easily solvable. But you will quickly realize that it is not really "yellow". For instance, {1,0,0} and {0,1,0} are both exactly the same distance from the yellow, but none perceive them as yellowish.
Then, is it a point with the proportion of R and G is 1:1? It is better but not entirely. Red and green have difference luminescence (thus different weights in grayscale conversion). Now, should we consider the weight? Well, then how about gamma and gamut? Then Euclidean distance becomes useless... I wouldn't even start the fact that human color perception is not linear but more of quadratic space... And then there is a whole story about chromaticity and visible spectrum (then different "yellow" there).

Getting the *closest* color for some color can be surprisingly hard.

Comment: Ok, But how do I find the most "yellowish" color with grayscale `.3`?

Answer (score 14):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For any color `c`:

```
f[c_, x_?NumericQ] := ColorConvert[Blend[{White, c, Black}, x], "Grayscale"][[1]]
```

Find a similar hue (ie lighter or darker) color for gray tone `.3`

```
findBlend[myColor_, Grayness_] := FindRoot[f[myColor, x] == Grayness, {x, 1/2}];
blend = findBlend[Blue, .3]
```

Test it

```
col = Quiet[Blend[{White, c, Black}, x] /. c -> Blue /. blend]
(* RGBColor[0.209932, 0.209932, 1.] *)
ColorConvert[col, "Grayscale"]
(*GrayLevel[0.3]*)
```

Testing the same hue:

```
{ColorConvert[col, "HSB"], ColorConvert[Blue,"HSB"]}
(* {Hue[0.666667,0.790068,1.],
    Hue[0.666667,1.,1.]
   }
*)
```

**Edit**

This could be made more efficient if needed by eliminating the `FindRoot[]` part since:

```
Plot[f[Blue, x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So you only need  to calculate `f[c. 1/2]` and then interpolate linearly to the left or to the right.

**Edit2** Answering @Sza's comment

Dirty code for the table at the beginning of this answer

```
c = Blue;
f[u_, x_?NumericQ] :=  
   Piecewise[{{ColorConvert[Blend[{White, u, Black}, x], "Grayscale"][[1]], 0 <= x <= 1}}];
findBlend[myColor_, Grayness_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[f[myColor, x] == Grayness, {x, 1/2}];
g[u_, x_?NumericQ] := Blend[{White, u, Black}, x];
GraphicsGrid[
 {Range[10]/10.,
  Graphics /@ ({#, Rectangle[]} & /@ (r = g[c, #] & /@ Table[x /. findBlend[c, p/10], {p, 10}])),
  ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"] & /@ Graphics /@ ({#, Rectangle[]} & /@ r)},
 Frame -> All]
```

Comment: Very nicely done. Here's a standalone version of that: `findGrayColor[color_, desiredTone_] := 
 Blend[{White, color, Black}, 
  Interpolation[
    Transpose[{{1, 
       First[ColorConvert[Blend[{White, color, Black}, 0.5], 
         "Grayscale"]], 0}, {0, 0.5, 1}}], InterpolationOrder -> 1][
   desiredTone]]`

Comment: How did you create the colour table at the top?  The code you gave works nicely, but the table at the top does not have blues of the same greyness as the greys below.

Comment: [Hmmm ...](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KlgJY.png)

Comment: @Szabolcs posted some code

Answer (score 14):

I once saw a formula

$$
\text{gray} = 0.3 \times \text{red} + 0.59 \times \text{green} + 0.11 \times \text{blue} 
$$

in the document for LaTeX package *xcolor* (section 6.3.1), wich points to a reference by Adobe: [*PostScript Language Reference Manual*](http://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf) (page 474)

It is similar to that mentioned in Yu-Sung Chang's answer, wish the document could be a useful supplement.

**Edit**

As about how to do it for chosen *hue*, I wrote this (row for different *saturation*, column for different *brightness*):

```
Clear[grayfunc]
grayfunc[h_, s_, b_] := Piecewise[{
   {b - (7 b s)/10 + (177 b h s)/50, 0 <= h < 1/6},
   {b + (19 b s)/100 - (9 b h s)/5, 1/6 <= h < 2/6},
   {b - (63 b s)/100 + (33 b h s)/50, 2/6 <= h < 3/6},
   {b + (147 b s)/100 - (177 b h s)/50, 3/6 <= h < 4/6},
   {b - (209 b s)/100 + (9 b h s)/5, 4/6 <= h < 5/6},
   {b - (b s)/25 - (33 b h s)/50, 5/6 <= h <= 1}
   }, 0]

Manipulate[
 Row[{ColorConvert[Rasterize[#, ImageSize -> 200], "Grayscale"], #}] &[
  Graphics[Table[{
     With[{s2 = If[gray >= grayfunc[h, 1, 1],
         Min[s, s2 /. Solve[grayfunc[h, s2, 1] == gray, s2][[1]]],
         s]},
      With[{b2 = b2 /. Solve[grayfunc[h, s2, b2] == gray, b2][[1]]},
       Hue[h, s2, b2]
       ]],
     Disk[{s, b}, .05]}, {s, 0, 1, .1}, {b, 0, 1, .1}], 
   ImageSize -> 200]
  ],
 {{gray, .6}, 0, 1},
 {{h, 1/6}, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And the *relative error* vs *saturation* and *brightness*:

```
Manipulate[
 Table[With[{s2 = If[gray >= grayfunc[h, 1, 1],
        Min[s, s2 /. Solve[grayfunc[h, s2, 1] == gray, s2][[1]]],
        s]},
     With[{b2 = b2 /. Solve[grayfunc[h, s2, b2] == gray, b2][[1]]},
      {s, b,
       ColorConvert[Hue[h, s2, b2], "Grayscale"][[1]]/gray - 1
         // Abs // Log[10, #] &
       }
      ]],
    {s, 0, 1, .1}, {b, 0, 1, .1}]
   // Flatten[#, 1] &
  // ListPlot3D[#, PlotRange -> All, ClippingStyle -> None,
    AxesLabel -> Join[
      Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ {s, b},
      {Rotate[
        Style[
         "relative error ( \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(log\), \\(10\)]\)-ed )",
         15, Bold], \[Pi]/2]
      }]] &,
 {{gray, .6}, 0, 1},
 {{h, 1/6}, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As the result shown, the grayscale is mainly related to brightness, consistent with our intuition.

The formula for `grayfunc` is derived by converting HSB to RGB using the formulae in **section 6.3.4** of the document for LaTeX package *xcolor*, then converting RGB to grayscale using the formula above.

Answer (score 9):

Just a starting point:
Buried in the documentation for GrayLevel is this example function:

```
RGBToGray[RGBColor[r_, g_, b_]] := GrayLevel[.299 r + .587 g + .144 b]
```

So each grayscale tone `desiredtone` corresponds to a family of colors satisfying

```
desiredtone == .299 r + .587 g + .144 b
```

*Update:* Unfortunately, this RGBToGray function does not use the same mapping as `ColorConvert[#,"Grayscale"]`:

[image]

Comment: Please make your code copyable.