# Ex-post monochome plots

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, plot-themes

I need to "monochromize" a large amount of plots (mostly coming from `ListPlot`) and export them to PDF. The problem is that I no longer have the data used to generate the plots, I only have notebooks that contain the plots. I attempted copy-pasting one plot and then something along the lines of `Show[plot,PlotTheme->"Monochrome"]` but that obviously did not work. I also tried `ColorConvert[plot,"Grayscale"]` but then the exported PDF was of extremely poor quality although I used the `ImageResolution` option of `Export`. One could, I think, extract the points from `FullForm` of the plots and simply plot them once more but this seems to be quite complicated given the quantity of the plots I have and their various structure (some of the `ListPlot` outputs contain two lists, some of them three, I also have a couple of simple graphics coming from `Plot`). Method of last resort is using some other software like Photoshop, but that makes the PDF many times larger - I need to use the plots with LaTeX so this would be the last option.

Comment: Related: [(32034)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32034/121)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Example plot:

```
Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x], Tan[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, just copy this plot from the notebook (using ctrl-C) and paste it in the front of following expression:

```
/. a : RGBColor[__] :> ColorConvert[a, "Grayscale"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The result:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In the same spirit of [Sjoerd's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/57/sjoerd-c-de-vries) answer, you can "steal" the theme-generated directives and replace them in the target plot.

With a dummy plot created using the desired theme,

```
dummyPlot = Plot[{1, 2, 3}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

> [image: Dummy Plot]

You can collect the generated directives,

```
directives = Cases[dummyPlot, Directive[a__] :> List@a, Infinity]
```

> {{Opacity[1.],GrayLevel[0],CapForm[Butt],AbsoluteThickness[1.6],AbsoluteDashing[{}]},<<2>>,{<<1>>}}

And apply them to the target plot (cycling through the list)!

```
plot = Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x], Tan[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π}];
plot /. Directive[a__] :> (directives = RotateLeft[directives]; Directive[Last@directives])
```

> [image: Re-colored Plot]

You must make a dummy plot with an equivalent number of plotted functions, otherwise you'll have to drop/add elements to the `directives` list.