# Matching colors in BarLegend and colorfunction

Tags: color, legending

How I can use `Hue` as color function in `BarLegend` in this density plot?

```
ShowLegend[
 DensityPlot[1 - Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 280, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 17, Black, Bold}, Frame -> True, 
  ColorFunction -> (Hue[1 - (0.7 # + 0.31)] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  PlotPoints -> 50], {ColorData[(Hue[1 - (0.7 # + 0.31)] &)] &, 10, 
  " 1", " 0", LegendPosition -> {1, 0.15}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16, Bold, Black}, LegendShadow -> None}]
```

[image]

Comment: Try `DensityPlot` only with `PlotLegends -> Automatic`. MMA V10.2

Comment: It is difficult to control the position and the size of the barlegend using Plotlegend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with others that you can have all the functionality without using the old `PlotLegends` package, I'd be interested in knowing if there are any options you want to add but cannot.  That being said, you can get `Hue` to work with `ShowLegend` easily enough.  You just had the color function formatted improperly.  There's no reason to wrap `Hue` with `ColorDataFunction`

```
ShowLegend[
 DensityPlot[1 - Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 280, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 17, Black, Bold}, Frame -> True, 
  ColorFunction -> (Hue[1 - (0.7 # + 0.31)] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  PlotPoints -> 50], {(Hue[1 - (0.7 # + 0.31)] &), 10, " 1", " 0", 
  LegendPosition -> {1, 0.15}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16, Bold, Black}, LegendShadow -> None}]
```

[image]

By the way, it looks like you are trying to recreate the MATLAB Jet color scheme by restricting the `Hue` values to between 0 and 0.7.  You can also use a Jet-like color scheme directly, which I've defined in this pastebin:

```
<< "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Dgck3tBL";
ShowLegend[
 DensityPlot[1 - Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 280, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 17, Black, Bold}, Frame -> True, 
  ColorFunction -> JetCM, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  PlotPoints -> 50], {JetCM, 10, " 1", " 0", 
  LegendPosition -> {1, 0.15}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16, Bold, Black}, LegendShadow -> None}]
```

[image]

Comment: I like the last one:-)

Comment: Yes, exactly, I want to create MATLAB Jet color scheme by restricting the Hue values to be  between 0 and 1.

Comment: A former coworker of mine took the jet color scheme and extracted the RGB values, and I made the JetCM color function from it.

Comment: Here are other options. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64514/9490

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
DensityPlot[
 1 - Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 3},
 ImageSize -> 280,
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[1 - (0.7 # + 0.31)] &),
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Below],
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

```
DensityPlot[
 1 - Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 3},
 ImageSize -> 280,
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 1}}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 200], {{1, 0}, {1, 1}}],
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Comment: using plotlegend is not helping to make the plot consistant with the barlegend, showlegend provide many options. I would like to know if there is a way to use a desired color with ColorData apart from "Rinbow", "TemperatureMap", SunsetColors, and ...etc