# How to mimic MATLAB parula color scheme efficiently?

Tags: color, matlab

Does anybody know how to mimic MATLAB's default scheme for `DensityPlot`, just like this picture shows:

[image: plot]

---

**update**

There are several answers already, Thank you very much.

But I am still wondering how to make the colorscheme more efficient.

Compare below cases:

```
<< "http://pastebin.com/raw/sqYFdrkY";
dd = Partition[Flatten[Table[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4, 0.01}, {y, -3, 3, 0.2}]], 2];
gnuplotTraditional = RGBColor[Sqrt[#], #^3, Sin[2 π #]] &;

ListDensityPlot[dd, PlotRange -> All, 
   ColorFunction -> ParulaCM]; // AbsoluteTiming
ListDensityPlot[dd, PlotRange -> All, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData["SunsetColors"]]; // AbsoluteTiming
ListDensityPlot[dd, PlotRange -> All, 
   ColorFunction -> gnuplotTraditional]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

The timing result on my computer is

```
{1.25649, Null}

{0.496294, Null}

{0.584826, Null}
```

So methods using `Blend` on color list is way too slow (consider `ListDensityPlot` is already very slow in *Mathematica* with large data).

So is there a succinct color formula for MATLAB's `parula`?

Comment: Jason B has extracted the RGB values and provided them as Mathematica colour maps in [this previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64514/484).

Comment: Hi, @Rahul. Thank you so much. But the color scheme seems not efficient. I updated my post

Comment: If you evaluate the `colorlist` in Jason's code, it's just as efficient: `mycm = ParulaCM /. s_Apply :> RuleCondition[s, True]`.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble - I had the function defined stupidly.  It should be as fast as internal color functions now.  https://pastebin.com/raw/jNX8y6YV

Comment: @JasonB. Thank you so much

Comment: I implemented both the old and new versions of `parula` in [this post](https://tpfto.wordpress.com/2018/03/05/on-emulating-the-parula-colormap-in-mathematica/).

Comment: Hi, @J.M. Thank you so much. You mentioned that " in both versions, MATLAB internally maintains a 256×3 matrix representing the RGB values comprising the colormap". But I check the doc https://cn.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/parula.html?lang=en , it says the default length is 64. How do you know it uses 256 length internally? And how to get this internal 256 representation?

Comment: The default is obtained from downsampling; in the M-file itself for `parula` (both versions), 256 RGB triplets are packed into a matrix. (But that should have been a comment on my post instead as opposed to a comment here.)

Comment: @J.M. Great! Thank you so much! I found the .m file

Answer (score 13):

I suggest you take a look at all available [color shemes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ColorSchemes.html).

The nearest one to your image seems to be `"BlueGreenYellow"`

So:

```
DensityPlot[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2) + y*x], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image]

Though, we can agree, this is not equal. 
We therefore can extract the matlab color sheme from your image:

```
{w, h} = ImageDimensions[matlabImage];
colorBar = ImageTake[matlabImage, All, {w - 95, w - 94}];
colorBarData = 
  RGBColor /@ 
   Select[Flatten[ImageData[colorBar], 1], 
    Total[#] != 3 && Total[#] != 0 &];
colorBarData = colorBarData[[3 ;; -3]];
matlabColorFunction[x_] := Blend[Reverse@colorBarData, x];
```

Where `matalbImage` is the image yoU've posted. 
We can use this therefore with

```
DensityPlot[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2) + y*x], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> matlabColorFunction, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image]

Which looks really equal to what you have given there.

Answer (score 7):

We can use color data from legend. Go to https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html  and copy the legend  and put it in Mathematica

[image]

```
colorName = {parula, jet, hsv, winter};

{col, row} = ImageDimensions /@ colorName // First;

ParulaMMA = 
  Module[{colorlist}, 
   colorlist = 
    Catenate@
     ImageData@ImageTake[parula, {Round[row/2], Round[row/2]}, All];
   Evaluate[Blend[RGBColor @@@ colorlist, #] &]];

JetMMA = Module[{colorlist}, 
   colorlist = 
    Catenate@
     ImageData@ImageTake[jet, {Round[row/2], Round[row/2]}, All];
   Evaluate[Blend[RGBColor @@@ colorlist, #] &]];

HsvMMA = Module[{colorlist}, 
   colorlist = 
    Catenate@
     ImageData@ImageTake[hsv, {Round[row/2], Round[row/2]}, All];
   Evaluate[Blend[RGBColor @@@ colorlist, #] &]];

WinterMMA = 
  Module[{colorlist}, 
   colorlist = 
    Catenate@
     ImageData@ImageTake[winter, {Round[row/2], Round[row/2]}, All];
   Evaluate[Blend[RGBColor @@@ colorlist, #] &]];   


 Legended[DensityPlot[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2) + y*x], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
    PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> #, PlotPoints -> 100, 
    ImageSize -> 220], BarLegend[{#, {0, 1}}]] & /@ {ParulaMMA, 
  JetMMA, HsvMMA, WinterMMA}
```

[image]

[image]