# Surface plot for matrices (Matlab-Mathematica)

Tags: plotting, matlab

[image][image][image]Now I am try to convert matlab file to mathematica,

This is the original Matlab command, [surf](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html), for making surface plots:

```
surf (xei , yei , zei , EE,'FaceColor ','interp ','FaceAlpha ' ,1.0 , 'LineWidth ' ,... 301
0.01 , 'EdgeAlpha ' ,0.2 , 'EdgeColor ','w');
```

If I want to plot the same matrix in Mathematica, which **correct** Plot Function shall I use?

For a better understanding, I put some convert codes here.

```
n = 70;
m = n/2;
CC = {{165.7, 63.9, 63.9, 0, 0, 0}, {63.9, 165.7, 63.9, 0, 0, 
    0}, {63.9, 63.9, 165.7, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 2*79.6, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
    0, 0, 2*79.6, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2*79.6}};
phi = N[Range[0, Pi, Pi/(m - 1)]];
theta = N[Range[0, 2*Pi, 2*Pi/(n - 1)]];
EE = ConstantArray[0, {m, n}];

xei = ConstantArray[0, {m, n}];
yei = ConstantArray[0, {m, n}];
zei = ConstantArray[0, {m, n}];

SS = Inverse[CC];



For[i = 1, i < n + 1, i++, For[j = 1, j < m + 1, j++,
  xhen = {{Sin[phi[[j]]]*Cos[theta[[i]]], 
     Sin[phi[[j]]]*Sin[theta[[i]]], Cos[phi[[j]]]}};
  (*xheng=Transpose[xhen];*)
  xiaoa = KroneckerProduct[Transpose[xhen], xhen];
  dbV = {{xiaoa[[1, 1]], xiaoa[[2, 2]], xiaoa[[3, 3]], 
     Sqrt[2]*xiaoa[[2, 3]], Sqrt[2]*xiaoa[[1, 3]], 
     Sqrt[2]*xiaoa[[1, 2]]}};
  (*dbV=Transpose[dbV];*)
  FFXX = SS . Transpose[dbV];
  (*FXXX=Transpose[dbV];*)
  EE[[j, i]] = 1/(dbV . FFXX);]]


For[i = 1, i < n + 1, i++, For[j = 1, j < m + 1, j++,
  xei[[j, i]] = EE[[j, i]]*Sin[phi[[j]]]*Cos[theta[[i]]];
  yei[[j, i]] = EE[[j, i]]*Sin[phi[[j]]]*Sin[theta[[i]]];
  zei[[j, i]] = EE[[j, i]]*Cos[phi[[j]]];]]
ListPlot3D[Transpose[{xei, yei, zei}]]
```

Comment: Try `ListPlot3D[Transpose[{xei, yei, zei}]]`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, xei,yei,zei are all not vector/list, if I use your method, then ListPlot3D::arrayerr: {<<1>>} must be a valid array or a list of valid arrays.

Comment: So, what is `xei`, yei`, `zei`? Example data is always welcome.

Comment: Hey @HenrikSchumacher, I put complete code here, thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, I also attached the matlab plot results

Comment: Try also `ListSurfacePlot3D` (along with `Flatten` as in Anton Antonov's answer).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, the cube is not closed form in the plot results in Mathematica, In Matlab, this cube contains no defects part. More Important, mesh gitter is also not the same for fine refinement in mathematica. also looking for your reply!

Comment: Is "plot the same matrix" necessary here?  Can you add some background information? For example, what's the meaning of `CC`? What are you trying to plot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit 4**

We can project it on `xy` plane by setting `z=0`.

```
n = 250;
m = n/2;
CC = {{165.7, 63.9, 63.9, 0, 0, 0}, {63.9, 165.7, 63.9, 0, 0, 
    0}, {63.9, 63.9, 165.7, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 2*79.6, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
    0, 0, 2*79.6, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2*79.6}};
phi = N[Range[0, Pi, Pi/(m - 1)]];
theta = N[Range[0, 2*Pi, 2*Pi/(n - 1)]];
EE = xei = yei = zei = ConstantArray[0, {m, n}];
SS = Inverse[CC];

Table[xhen = {Sin[phi[[j]]]*Cos[theta[[i]]], 
    Sin[phi[[j]]]*Sin[theta[[i]]], Cos[phi[[j]]]};
  xiaoa = KroneckerProduct[xhen, xhen];
  dbV = {xiaoa[[1, 1]], xiaoa[[2, 2]], xiaoa[[3, 3]], 
    Sqrt[2]*xiaoa[[2, 3]], Sqrt[2]*xiaoa[[1, 3]], 
    Sqrt[2]*xiaoa[[1, 2]]};
  FFXX = SS.dbV;
  EE[[j, i]] = 1/(dbV.FFXX), {i, n}, {j, m}];

Table[xei[[j, i]] = EE[[j, i]]*Sin[phi[[j]]]*Cos[theta[[i]]];
  yei[[j, i]] = EE[[j, i]]*Sin[phi[[j]]]*Sin[theta[[i]]];
  zei[[j, i]] = EE[[j, i]]*Cos[phi[[j]]];, {i, n}, {j, m}];

data = Transpose[Flatten /@ {xei, yei, zei, EE}];
data[[All, 3]] = 0;
color = Blend["ThermometerColors", Rescale[#, MinMax@EE]] &;



Legended[Graphics3D[{color[Last[#]], AbsolutePointSize[20], 
     Point[Most[#]]} & /@ data, ImageSize -> Large, 
  ViewPoint -> Above, Boxed -> False], 
 BarLegend[{color, MinMax@EE}, LegendMarkerSize -> {22, 400}]]
```

[image]

Or

```
data = Transpose[Flatten /@ {xei, yei, zei, EE}];
data = data[[All, {1, 2, 4}]];

Legended[Graphics[{color[Last[#]], AbsolutePointSize[20], 
     Point[Most[#]]} & /@ data, ImageSize -> Large], 
 BarLegend[{color, MinMax@EE}, LegendMarkerSize -> {22, 400}]]
```

[image]

Or you achieve this by using @xzczd

```
CC = {{165.7, 63.9, 63.9, 0, 0, 0}, {63.9, 165.7, 63.9, 0, 0, 
    0}, {63.9, 63.9, 165.7, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 2 79.6, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
    0, 0, 2 79.6, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 79.6}};
SS = Inverse[CC];
xhen = {Sin[phi] Cos[theta], Sin[phi] Sin[theta], Cos[phi]};
xiaoa = Outer[Times, xhen, xhen];
dbV = {xiaoa[[1, 1]], xiaoa[[2, 2]], xiaoa[[3, 3]], 
   Sqrt[2] xiaoa[[2, 3]], Sqrt[2] xiaoa[[1, 3]], 
   Sqrt[2] xiaoa[[1, 2]]};
EE = 1/dbV.SS.dbV;

SphericalPlot3D[EE, {phi, 0, Pi}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, phi, theta, r}, 
   ColorData["ThermometerColors"][r]], ViewPoint -> Above, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

**Edit 3**

You can increase number of point by increasing `n`.

[image]

```
 {col, row} = ImageDimensions@parula;
    ParulaMMA = 
      Module[{colorlist}, 
       colorlist = 
        Catenate@
         ImageData@ImageTake[parula, {Round[row/2], Round[row/2]}, All];
       Evaluate[Blend[RGBColor @@@ colorlist, Rescale[#, MinMax@EE]] &]];



n = 250;
m = n/2;
CC = {{165.7, 63.9, 63.9, 0, 0, 0}, {63.9, 165.7, 63.9, 0, 0, 
    0}, {63.9, 63.9, 165.7, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 2*79.6, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
    0, 0, 2*79.6, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2*79.6}};
phi = N[Range[0, Pi, Pi/(m - 1)]];
theta = N[Range[0, 2*Pi, 2*Pi/(n - 1)]];
EE = xei = yei = zei = ConstantArray[0, {m, n}];
SS = Inverse[CC];

Table[
  xhen = {Sin[phi[[j]]]*Cos[theta[[i]]], 
    Sin[phi[[j]]]*Sin[theta[[i]]], Cos[phi[[j]]]};
  xiaoa = KroneckerProduct[xhen, xhen];
  dbV = {xiaoa[[1, 1]], xiaoa[[2, 2]], xiaoa[[3, 3]], 
    Sqrt[2]*xiaoa[[2, 3]], Sqrt[2]*xiaoa[[1, 3]], 
    Sqrt[2]*xiaoa[[1, 2]]};
  FFXX = SS.dbV;
  EE[[j, i]] = 1/(dbV.FFXX), {i, n}, {j, m}];

Table[xei[[j, i]] = EE[[j, i]]*Sin[phi[[j]]]*Cos[theta[[i]]];
  yei[[j, i]] = EE[[j, i]]*Sin[phi[[j]]]*Sin[theta[[i]]];
  zei[[j, i]] = EE[[j, i]]*Cos[phi[[j]]];, {i, n}, {j, m}];

data = Transpose[Flatten /@ {xei, yei, zei, EE}];


Legended[Graphics3D[{ParulaMMA[Last[#]], AbsolutePointSize[20], 
     Point[Most[#]]} & /@ data, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotRange -> {{-200, 200}, {-200, 200}, {-200, 200}}], 
 BarLegend[{ParulaMMA, MinMax@EE}, LegendMarkerSize -> {22, 400}]]
```

[image]

Or

Mathematica's built in gradient color

```
color = Blend["ThermometerColors", Rescale[#, MinMax@EE]] &;

Legended[Graphics3D[{color[Last[#]], AbsolutePointSize[20], 
     Point[Most[#]]} & /@ data, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotRange -> {{-200, 200}, {-200, 200}, {-200, 200}}], 
 BarLegend[{color, MinMax@EE}, LegendMarkerSize -> {22, 400}]]
```

[image]

**Edit 2**
Here is another way to visualize it. [see this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161647/how-to-mimic-matlab-parula-color-scheme-efficiently/161683#161683) for parula color.

```
data = Transpose[Flatten /@ {xei, yei, zei, EE}];
```

[image]

```
{col, row} = ImageDimensions@parula;
ParulaMMA = 
  Module[{colorlist}, 
   colorlist = 
    Catenate@
     ImageData@ImageTake[parula, {Round[row/2], Round[row/2]}, All];
   Evaluate[Blend[RGBColor @@@ colorlist, Rescale[#, MinMax@EE]] &]];

Legended[Graphics3D[{ParulaMMA[Last[#]], Sphere[Most[#], 20]} & /@ 
   data, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotRange -> {{-200, 200}, {-200, 200}, {-200, 200}}], 
 BarLegend[{ParulaMMA, MinMax@EE}, LegendMarkerSize -> {22, 400}]]
```

[image]

**Original Answer**

This is the closest I can get.

```
data = Transpose[Flatten /@ {xei, yei, zei, EE}];

ListPointPlot3D[List /@ Most /@ data, 
 PlotStyle -> ({AbsolutePointSize[22], 
      Blend["BlueGreenYellow", Rescale[#, MinMax@EE]]} & /@ 
    Last /@ data), BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for figuring this out! It looks much better, but surface is not  smoothly in Mathematica.

Comment: If I run this plot, I get bugs, namely:   ImageDimensions::imginv: Expecting an image or graphics instead of parula.  Set::shape: Lists {col,row} and ImageDimensions[parula] are not the same shape.  ImageTake::imginv: Expecting an image or graphics instead of parula.

Comment: You need to define parula. got to here https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html    and copy parula and paste it in Mathematica notebook

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, this problem is solved!

Comment: @Okkes Dulgerci, is there also a simple command that we can get a 2D results(projection:3D-2D)

Comment: @ABCDEMMM See my edit.

Comment: thanks, may I ask one more question,  is it possible that we can plot “contour” line  in 2D using simple commands (continue)?

Comment: If you use xzczd 's code, you can modify it for mesh `SphericalPlot3D[EE, {phi, 0, Pi}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, phi, theta, r}, 
   ColorData["ThermometerColors"][r]], ViewPoint -> Above, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> 30, 
 MeshStyle -> {Black, Thick, Opacity[1]}]`

Comment: I mean this kind of "contour ": http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AnisotropicElasticity/

Comment: Which one you wanna use? `SphericalPlot3D` or `Graphics3D`

Comment: only based on your method/concept, how can we plot the "one contour" (as you see the right side jpg in the links)

Comment: Use `data = Transpose[Flatten /@ {xei, yei, zei, EE}] // Chop;` and `ListLinePlot[Cases[data, {_, _, 0, _}][[All, 1 ;; 2]], 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True]` Basically we find the points where `z=0` and plot only `xy` pairs

Comment: This problem is totally solved in very easy way in MMA, thank you!

Comment: I wrote a compact emulation of `parula()` [here](https://tpfto.wordpress.com/2018/03/05/on-emulating-the-parula-colormap-in-mathematica/).

Answer (score 5):

I should have read your question and the [`surf` help page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) more carefully -- your are using four matrices `{xei, yei, zei, EE}`.

Here is one way to use `EE` for the surface color:

```
colorRules = 
  Most[#] -> Last[#] & /@ Transpose[Flatten /@ {xei, yei, zei, EE}];

ListSurfacePlot3D[Transpose[Flatten /@ {xei, yei, zei}], 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, {x, y, z} /. colorRules]]
```

[image]

I assume this can be improved.

### *Second try*

I understand that the following plots are "volume" density and contour plots, not a surface density plot which you want. But I think they are close...

Using `ListDensityPlot3D`:

```
ListDensityPlot3D[Transpose[Flatten /@ {xei, yei, zei, EE}]]
```

[image]

Another plot that is close is made with `ListContourPlot3D`:

```
ListContourPlot3D[Transpose[Flatten /@ {xei, yei, zei, EE}], 
 Contours -> 30, Mesh -> None, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

### *First take*

*(More of a comment to find out what OP wants...)*

Evaluating the code you posted we have these dimensions for `{xei, yei, zei}`:

```
Dimensions /@ {xei, yei, zei}    
(* {{35, 70, 1, 1}, {35, 70, 1, 1}, {35, 70, 1, 1}} *)
```

I strongly suspect that what you want is this plot:

```
ListPlot3D[Transpose[Flatten /@ {xei, yei, zei}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: But It still contains the bugs as the cube is not closed form. looking for your reply! Thanks

Comment: the mesh gitter also not correct.

Comment: why 'ListSurfacePlot3D' is not correct in Mathematica?

Comment: @FEAPMAN "why 'ListSurfacePlot3D' is not correct in Mathematica?" -- I do not know is it correct or not. Meaning, `ListSurfacePlot3D` might have a bug, or the problem might be in your data and a particular "feature" of `ListSurfacePlot3D`... It is a good idea to investigate, but I am not doing that anytime soon.

Answer (score 4):

OK, though OP doesn't reply to my comment, I'd like to post a possible answer. If OP just wants to obtain that plot and "plot the same matrix" is not necessary, then the solution is quite simple. We don't need to discretize the analytic solution and transform the coordinate etc., because we have `SphericalPlot3D`:

```
CC = {{165.7, 63.9, 63.9, 0, 0, 0}, {63.9, 165.7, 63.9, 0, 0, 0}, {63.9, 63.9, 165.7, 0, 
    0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 2 79.6, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 2 79.6, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 79.6}};
SS = Inverse[CC];
xhen = {Sin[phi] Cos[theta], Sin[phi] Sin[theta], Cos[phi]};
xiaoa = Outer[Times, xhen, xhen];
dbV = {xiaoa[[1, 1]], xiaoa[[2, 2]], xiaoa[[3, 3]], Sqrt[2] xiaoa[[2, 3]], 
   Sqrt[2] xiaoa[[1, 3]], Sqrt[2] xiaoa[[1, 2]]};
EE = 1/dbV.SS.dbV;

SphericalPlot3D[EE, {phi, 0, Pi}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, phi, theta, r}, ColorData["AvocadoColors"][r]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I believe the definition of `EE` can be simplified further, but without background information it's somewhat beyond my reach.

Comment: this plot results can show us the Anisotropic Elasticity (similar to the work: "Anisotropic Elasticity"
http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AnisotropicElasticity/
Wolfram Demonstrations Project
Published: March 7 2011)

Comment: The original code is wrotten in Matlab which needs  to discretize the analytic solution and transform the coordinate etc. Now Mathematica show its strongly numerical ability in this case, cheers!

Comment: @FEAPMAN Is `EE` defined by some kind of rotation? Can you elaborate a little on this part?

Comment: EE is elasticity tensor.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM I know, but what I'm interested in is, why is it defined in this way?`xiaoa` and `dbV` looks like something related to rotation or coordinate transform, and I believe they can be simplified, but without more background information it's beyond my reach.