# 3D plot of a tensor

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, tensors

How to plot a tensor in three dimensions. For example, let us take a dielectric constant tensor of rank two.

```
K = {{3000, 885, 650}, {2000, 885, 540}, {650, 540, 1000}};
```

Also, alternatively, is there any Mathematica function which can convert the tensor to a function of (theta, phi), so that it can be plotted easily by using SphericalPlot3D.

Will be thankful for any suggestion.

Comment: E.g.:K = {{3000, 885, 650}, {2000, 885, 540}, {650, 540, 1000}};   ContourPlot3D[{x, y, z}.K.{x, y, z} == 100, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 
  1}, {z, -1, 1}]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Still have two doubts. (1) Why to equate [{x, y, z}.K.{x, y, z} with 100. (2) How to generalize the procedure, say for elasticity tensor of 4th rank, which is generally represented by a 6x6 matrix? Thanks

Comment: 100 simply gives the size of the ellipsoid. For a tensor of higher degree you may calculate the main axes by using "Eigensystem".

Comment: will look into the EigenSystem option. Alternatively, tensor elements can be represented by summation over direction cosines also. How can the direction cosines be converted to functions of orientations (say (theta, phi) in spherical systems). Any idea about this route? I have seen some examples, but not able to figure out the intermediate steps. Will appreciate if you can suggest some references.Thanks

Comment: But the direction cosines are, as the name implies, the cosines of the angles between the direction and the axes.

Comment: Yes. For example any element of a (say) third rank tensor can be given as A'_ijk = a_il * a_jm * a_kn * A_lmn' summed over indicies l, m, n. Then all direction cosines a's can be transformed to functions of spherical coordinates (theta, phi). Though  I am not able to figure out this step yet.

Comment: For the cartesian comp. of a vector v, the direction cosines are: ax= vx/Norm; ay= vy/Norm; az= z/Norm. If you write the cart. comp of a unit vec. using phi and theta: ax= Cos[phi] Sin[theta]; ay= Sin[phi] Sin[theta]; az= Cos[theta]

Comment: 1. Please avoid asking distinct questions in one post. 2. What do you mean by "plot a tensor"? `MatrixPlot@K`? Or something like this?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/176915/1871

Comment: Is your tensor really unsymmetric?