# Compare MMA program with MATLAB program by plotting the same equation

Tags: plotting, matlab, implicit

**Cross-posted [in Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2440782).**

---

Firstly, the MATLAB program is

```
t = 0;
A = 2;
c1 = 1;
c2 = 1;
c = 1/25;
omega = 2;

[xi,eta]=meshgrid(-5:0.1:5,-4:0.1:6);

P = ((2*sinh(xi+omega*t))./(3*cosh(xi+omega*t)))+((5*sinh(xi+omega*t))./(6*cosh(xi+omega*t)).^3)+0.9;
Q = -(sinh(eta))./(cosh(eta));
x = xi-2.5*tanh(xi+omega*t);
y = eta;

Px = -(sech(xi+omega*t)).^2;
Qy = -(sech(eta)).^2;

u = ((A-c1.*c2).*Px.*Qy)./(1+c1.*P+c2.*Q+c.*P.*Q).^2;
view([-45 70]);

surf(x,y,u);
xlabel('x','FontSize',26,'FontName','Times New Roman','FontAngle', 'italic')
ylabel('y','FontSize',26,'FontName','Times New Roman','FontAngle', 'italic')
zlabel('$u$','interpreter','latex','FontSize',24,'FontName','Times New Roman','FontAngle', 'italic')
```

and it comes

[image]

With the same equation, the MMA program is

```
ω = 2;
A = 2; Subscript[c, 1] = Subscript[c, 2] = 1; Subscript[c, 3] = 1/25;
px = -Sech[ξ + ω t]^2; p = (2 Sinh[ξ + ω t])/(
  3 Cosh[ξ + ω t]) + (5 Sinh[ξ + ω t])/(
  6 Cosh[ξ + ω t]^3) + 0.9;
qy = -Sech[η]^2; q = -(Sinh[η]/Cosh[η]);
func[ξ_, η_, 
   t_] = ((A - Subscript[c, 1] Subscript[c, 2]) px qy)/(1 + 
      Subscript[c, 1] p + Subscript[c, 2] q + Subscript[c, 3] p q)^2 //
     Rationalize // Simplify;
xyToXiEta[x_, y_, t_] := 
  NSolve[{x == ξ - 2.5 Tanh[ξ + 2 t], 
    y == η}, {ξ, η}, Reals];
With[{t = 0}, 
 ListPlot3D[
  Flatten[Table[{x, y, func[ξ, η, t]} /. 
     xyToXiEta[x, y, t], {x, -2, 2, 0.04}, {y, -1, 5, 0.04}], 2], 
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 2}}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]]
```

and it comes

[image].

Thanks Gianluca Gorni for providing the MMA program.

It is obvious that the MATLAB picture forms like a bridge with empty space under it. However, the MMA picture is solid. I think it might be caused by ``NSolve" in MMA.

How can I improve the MMA program to make it like MATLAB's result?

Comment: Why not `ParametricPlot3D`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your Mathematica plot. from your code.  Please verify that it is correct by copying your code to a fresh notebook and running it.

Comment: Thank you for your notification, the code has been corrected and edited.

Comment: ParametricPlot3D is an excellent choice. Cause that I am a rookie, it would be better if you could modify the programme.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, one should use `ParametricPlot3D` for the task:

```
t = 0;
A = 2;
c1 = 1;
c2 = 1;
c = 1/25;
omega = 2;
With[{sinh = Sinh, cosh = Cosh, tanh = Tanh, sech = Sech},
  P = ((2 sinh@(xi + omega t))/(3 cosh@(xi + omega t))) + ((5 sinh@(xi + 
           omega t))/(6 cosh@(xi + omega t))^3) + 0.9;
  Q = -(sinh@(eta))/(cosh@(eta));
  x = xi - 2.5 tanh@(xi + omega t);
  y = eta;
  
  Px = -(sech@(xi + omega t))^2;
  Qy = -(sech@(eta))^2;
  
  u = ((A - c1 c2) Px Qy)/(1 + c1 P + c2 Q + c P Q)^2];

ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, u}, {xi, -5, 5}, {eta, -4, 6}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.4}, 
 PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: why not first create the nodes ("meshgrid"), then plot them in MMA?

Comment: @a Because it's not necessary to discretize manually in MMA, as you've already known: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176915/surface-plot-for-matrices-matlab-mathematica/177026#comment464500_177026

Answer (score 7):

For completion I also post here my Wolfram Community answer. A direct translation of the code is not possible as that function does not exist (ListParametricPlot3D or so). But we can recreate the graphic "manually" by recreating the polygons, or rewrite the code to use ParametricPlot3D (preferred and nicer), I included both:

```
t = 0;
A = 2;
c1 = 1;
c2 = 1;
c = 1/25;
omega = 2;

pts = Array[List/*N, 101 {1, 1}, {{-5, 5}, {-4, 6}}];
{xi, eta} = {pts[[All, All, 1]], pts[[All, All, 2]]};

P = 2 Sinh[xi + omega t]/(3 Cosh[xi + omega t]) + (5 Sinh[xi + omega t]/(6 Cosh[xi + omega t])^3) + 0.9;
Q = -Sinh[eta]/Cosh[eta];
x = xi - 2.5 Tanh[xi + omega t];
y = eta;

Px = -Sech[xi + omega t]^2;
Qy = -Sech[eta]^2;

u = (A - c1 c2) Px Qy/(1 + c1 P + c2 Q + c P Q)^2;

pols = BlockMap[{{#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], #[[2, 1]]}, {#[[2, 1]], #[[1, 
   2]], #[[2, 2]]}} &, Transpose[{x, y, u}, {3, 1, 2}], {2, 2}, {1, 1}];
pols = Catenate[Catenate[pols]];
Graphics3D[Polygon[pols], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[funcu]
funcu[xi_, eta_] := Module[{t = 0, A = 2, c1 = 1, c2 = 1, c = 1/25, omega = 2, P, Q, x, y, Px, Qy},
  P = 2 Sinh[xi + omega t]/(3 Cosh[xi + omega t]) + (5 Sinh[xi + omega t]/(6 Cosh[xi + omega t])^3) + 0.9;
  Q = -Sinh[eta]/Cosh[eta];
  x = xi - 2.5 Tanh[xi + omega t];
  y = eta;
  Px = -Sech[xi + omega t]^2;
  Qy = -Sech[eta]^2;
  {x, y, (A - c1 c2) Px Qy/(1 + c1 P + c2 Q + c P Q)^2}
]
ParametricPlot3D[funcu[xi, eta], {xi, -5, 5}, {eta, -4, 6}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 80, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, \[Phi], \[Theta]}, ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"][z]]]
```

[image]