# Pretty heat maps

Tags: plotting

I would like to create a heat map like that following:

[image]

This code:

```
f[x_, y_] := (x^2 + y^2)^2 Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/5)]
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]
```

gives me the following:

[image]

Is there a color scheme that looks more than the first picture? Is there a way to add labels and legend that are part of the picture? I would like to just export it to pdf and add it in latex.

PS. By the way, I am not asking about a table of 4 heat maps, I just need to know how to create this kind of heat maps.

Comment: This looks like Python plasma color.

Answer (score 8):

The color looks like Python's plasma color. When we follow this strategies on [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161647/how-to-mimic-matlab-parula-color-scheme-efficiently/161683#161683) answers and get the color gradient [here](https://www.kennethmoreland.com/color-advice/plasma/plasma.svg) and copy paste and cropped it carefully, we get the following plot.[image]

```
{col, row} = ImageDimensions@plasma;

plasmaMMA = 
  Module[{colorlist}, 
   colorlist = 
    Catenate@
     ImageData@ImageTake[plasma, {Round[row/2], Round[row/2]}, All];
   Evaluate[Blend[RGBColor @@@ colorlist, #] &]];
f[x_, y_] := (x^2 + y^2)^2 Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/5)]
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, ColorFunction -> plasmaMMA]
```

[image]

You can repeat the same procedure for [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbkaN.png) img. Crop the bar legend from the image get the figure.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need precisely that scheme, the named gradient scheme `SunsetColors` is pretty close to what you want:

```
f[x_, y_] := (x^2 + y^2)^2 Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/5)]
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["SunsetColors"]]
```

[image]

There are several named color schemes built into Mathematica.  The easiest way to browse through them is to type "`ColorData`" into an input cell and then select "Choose Color Scheme" from the contextual menu that pops up under your input.

Alternately, you can use `Blend` to roll your own scheme that linearly interpolates between purple, orange, and yellow:

```
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Purple, Orange, Yellow}, #1] &)]
```

[image]

This can be tweaked by replacing the arguments `Purple`, `Orange`, or `Yellow` with other `RGBColor` objects.  (For example, the `Purple` used by Mathematica is redder, while the purple color in your examples is a bluer shade that I might call "violet".  Mathematica's `Yellow` also has a higher saturation than the yellow in your examples.)  The "speed" of the interpolation can also be controlled;  consult the `Blend` documentation for details.

Comment: The standard color maps are also listed in [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ColorSchemes.html).

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the previous suggestions for changing the color scheme, here's how you can add labels and export it to a pdf you can use in Latex

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]; (*Change directory for output*)

f[x_, y_] := (x^2 + y^2)^2 Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/5)]
p1 = DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5},
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["SunsetColors"], (*Change color scheme*)
  FrameLabel -> {"x label", "y label"}, (*Add some labels*)
  LabelStyle -> {Black, 15},(*Change label style*)
  PlotLegends -> True (*Add a legend*)
  ] 
Export["filename.pdf", p1] (*Export to file*)
```

[image]

You might also find the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html) of `DensityPlot[]` useful.

Answer (score 4):

You can make a custom color function [`Blend`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blend.html)ing `Purple` and `Yellow`:

```
f[x_, y_] := (x^2 + y^2)^2 Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/5)]

DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Purple, Yellow}, #] &)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to extract a color scheme from one you like from the web.  I found an image of the FLIR iron pallete from this [blog post](http://ramphastosramblings.blogspot.com/2014/03/choosing-appropriate-colour-palette-for.html).  By executing the following code, you can blend a color scheme and compare the results to "SunsetColors".

```
img = Import[
   "http://lh6.ggpht.com/-ML05X6b7Acs/UyIoexgMBTI/AAAAAAAAF0g/\
A80fhSA2rks/Iron%252520Gradient.png?imgmax=800"];
dims = ImageDimensions[img];
colors = RGBColor[#] & /@ 
   Reverse[ImageData[img][[2 ;; dims[[2]] - 1, 
      IntegerPart@(dims[[1]]/2)]]];
f[x_, y_] := (x^2 + y^2)^2 Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/5)]
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["SunsetColors"]]
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[colors, #] &)]
```

## Sunset Colors

[image: Sunset Colors]

## FLIR Iron Pallete

[image: FLIR Iron Pallete]

Answer (score 2):

[Colormaps for linear visual perception AND grayscale printing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127306/colormaps-for-linear-visual-perception-and-grayscale-printing) shows various ways to get Matplotlib's color schemes.  Here's "inferno":

```
(*https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127332/4999*)
ClearAll[MPLColorMap]
<< "http://pastebin.com/raw/pFsb4ZBS";

MPLColorMap["Inferno"]

DensityPlot[(x^2 + y^2)^2 Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/5)], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5},
  ColorFunction -> MPLColorMap["Inferno"]]
```

[image]

[Is there an easy way to use Matteo Niccoli's perceptual color maps for 2D plots in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64513/is-there-an-easy-way-to-use-matteo-niccolis-perceptual-color-maps-for-2d-plots) also presents some color schemes