# Filling gradually varied colors under a function curve

Tags: plotting, graphics

I would like to plot a figure with a top to bottom gradient like this:
[image]

I drew this figure using Matlab. Is it possible to plot a similar one using Mathematica?
I googled some posts, but I do not know how to do this. Is it possible to do it by "filling"?
Thank you!

1. According to Bob's idea, I tried this code:

   ```
    mx[x_] = -100*x*Exp[-69.3147*x^2]; (*This is my function*)
    Show[RegionPlot[
      mx[x] <= y <= 0 || 0 <= y <= mx[x], {x, -0.5, 0.5}, {y, -5.5, 5.5}, 
      ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AspectRatio -> 0.75, 
      BoundaryStyle -> None], Plot[mx[x], {x, -0.5, 0.5}], 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Darker[Blue], Thick]]
   ```

I got this figure:
[image]

Why the right tail is incompleted? If we look the figure carefully, the peak position is also not perfectly match the curve.

2. According to Michael's and kglr's idea, I tried this code:

   ```
    mx[t_] = t*Exp[-69.3147*t^2]; (*This is my function*)
    Get["https://pastebin.com/raw/gN4wGqxe"]
    JetCM = With[{colorlist = RGBColor @@@ jetColors}, 
       Blend[colorlist, #] &];
    ParametricPlot[{t, y*mx[t]}, {t, -0.5, 0.5}, {y, 0, 1}, 
      PlotRange -> All, 
      ColorFunction -> (JetCM[#2 + (25 #2^2 (#2 - 1/2) (1 - #2)^2)/(1 + 
              100 (#2 - 1/2)^2)] &), AspectRatio -> 0.75, Axes -> False, 
      BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Black}] /. 
     Line[v_, opts___] :> Line[v[[2 ;; -2]], opts]
   ```

Then I got this figure:
[image]
The curve is not smooth anymore.

3. By the way, how to fill an inverse raninbow color?
   I tried this:

   ```
    ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", "Reverse"}]
   ```

But it does not work.

Comment: A related example appears in the documentation, but it's in the other direction: `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[x]], 
 Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Automatic]`

Comment: Increase the `PlotPoints` to get a smoother curve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the Matlab color scheme from [this site, courtesy of @JasonB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64514/4999):

```
(*https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64514/4999*)
Get["https://pastebin.com/raw/gN4wGqxe"]
JetCM = With[{colorlist = RGBColor @@@ jetColors}, 
   Blend[colorlist, #] &];

ParametricPlot[{s, t Sin[s]}, {s, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> (JetCM[#2 + (25 #2^2 (#2 - 1/2) (1 - #2)^2)/(
       1 + 100 (#2 - 1/2)^2)] &),
  AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False, 
  BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Black}] /. 
 Line[v_, opts___] :> Line[v[[2 ;; -18]], opts]
```

It's probably easier just plotting sine twice and composing than to postprocess the boundary `Line`:

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot[{s, t Sin[s]}, {s, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> (JetCM[#2 + (25 #2^2 (#2 - 1/2) (1 - #2)^2)/(
       1 + 100 (#2 - 1/2)^2)] &), AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None],
 Plot[Sin[s], {s, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}]
 ]
```

I'm not sure how the Matlab scaling of the color gradient was done.  It seemed to require some funky transformation to approximate the OP's image.  One can simply use `ColorFunction -> (JetCM[#2] &)` if the exact gradient is not needed.

Both figures look like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Michael. Thank you for your methods. I tried your code, but the curve is not smooth anymore. Please see above, I just updated this post. :_)

Comment: @Mr.2023 Increase `PlotPoints`. For example `PlotPoints -> 30`. (Probably don't need `/. Line[v_, opts___] :> Line[v[[2 ;; -2]], opts]`....or use something like `/. Line[v_, opts___] :> Line[v[[2 ;; -32]], opts]`)

Comment: Michael, it works. Now the curve becomes smooth.:-) Do you know how to fill an inverse Rainbow color? I mean that fill red color in down part and blue color up part.

Comment: @Mr.2023 In the `ColorFunction`, the argument `#2` is scaled to run from `0` to `1`.  So change each instance of `#2` to `1 - #2`.

Comment: Michael, Thank you for your help. Used your method, I got the final figure what I expected. :_) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 5):

Use [`RegionPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html) for the filling

```
Show[
 RegionPlot[
  0 <= y <= Sin[x] && 0 <= x <= Pi ||
   Sin[x] <= y <= 0 && -Pi <= x <= 0,
  {x, -4, 4}, {y, -1.1, 1.1},
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  AspectRatio -> 0.75,
  BoundaryStyle -> None],
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}],
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Darker[Blue], Thick]]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1), as this is more natural and faster than my `DensityPlot`. Also for the colour, try: `ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[y]]` to get a look closer to OP's question.

Comment: Hi, Bob. Thank you. I tried your method. It works but there exist some problems. Please see above, I just edit the post and show my progress.:_)

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to do this with a density plot if you're prepared to plug in the inequalities:

```
Show[
 DensityPlot[
  If[(0 < y < Sin[x]) || (Sin[x] < y < 0), y, ∞], {x, -π, π}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[x]], PlotPoints -> 30]
 , Plot[Sin[x], {x, -π, π}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}]
 ]
```

[image: vertical filling effect]

Comment: +1. You can also plot `y` and use e.g. `RegionFunction -> 
 Function[{x, y}, (y > 0 && y < Sin[x]) || (y < 0 && y > Sin[x])]`

Comment: Or you can use `ConditionalExpression` as well: `ConditionalExpression[y, (0 < y < Sin[x]) || (Sin[x] < y < 0)]`

Answer (score 4):

```
ParametricPlot[{x, t Sin[x]}, {x, -π, π}, {t, 0, 1},
 AspectRatio -> 1, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#2] &),
 MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, Mesh -> {{1}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Opacity[1], Black], Axes -> False, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

With the second example in OP:

```
mx[x_] := -100 x Exp[-69.3147*x^2];

ParametricPlot[{x, t mx[x]}, {x, -0.5, 0.5}, {t, 0, 1},
 AspectRatio -> 1, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#2] &),
 MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, Mesh -> {{1}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Opacity[1], Black], Axes -> False, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Use `ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"Rainbow", "Reverse"}][#2] &)` to get

[image]

At the cost of some eye strain to find the right scaling ranges, we can use `"VisibleSpectrum"` to get close to the picture in OP:

```
colorFunction = ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][
    If[# <= 0, Rescale[#, {-1, 0}, {450, 510}], Rescale[#, {0, 1}, {550, 660}]]] &;

ParametricPlot[{x, t Sin[x]}, {x, -π, π}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1,  
 ColorFunction -> (colorFunction[#2] &), 
 MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{1}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Opacity[1], Black], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 Axes -> False, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

And for the second example in OP:

```
colorFunction = ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][If[# <= 0,
     Rescale[#, {-5, 0}, {450, 510}], Rescale[#, {0, 5}, {550, 660}]]] &;

ParametricPlot[{x, t mx[x]}, {x, -0.5, 0.5}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, ColorFunction -> (colorFunction[#2] &), 
 MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, Mesh -> {{1}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Opacity[1], Black], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Axes -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, kglr. Thank you for your help. I tried the "ParametricPlot" method, but new problems apear. I just updated this post and show my progress of this problem. Could you read it and show me some possible solutions? :-)

Comment: Hi, kglr. Thank you! I got it. :_)

Comment: @Mr.2023, to get a smoother curve use a large value for `PlotPoints`, e.g.,`PlotPoints -> 100`. An for reversing the color function use `ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"Rainbow", "Reverse"}][#2] &)`.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use a [`LinearGradientImage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearGradientImage.html) as the setting for `PlotStyle`:

```
mx[x_] := -100 x Exp[-69.3147*x^2];

ParametricPlot[{x, t mx[x]}, {x, -0.5, 0.5}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, Mesh -> {{1}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Opacity[1], Black], Axes -> False, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[1, Texture[LinearGradientImage[{Top, Bottom} -> "Rainbow"]]], 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &)]
```

[image]

Use `LinearGradientImage[{Top, Bottom} -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", "Reversed"}]]` or  `LinearGradientImage[{Bottom, Top} -> "Rainbow"]` to get:

[image]

Comment: yes.Thank you:_)