# Colorfunction in 3D plot

Tags: plotting

I used Matlab jet color by applying the steps in [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64513/is-there-an-easy-way-to-use-matteo-niccolis-perceptual-color-maps-for-2d-plots/64514#64514) as follows.

```
     Plot3D[Abs[E^(I (t/2 + x)) (Coth[t + x])], {x, -2, 2}, {t, -2, 2}, 
   ColorFunction -> #, PlotPoints -> 15, PlotRange -> All] & /@ {Hue, 
  JetCM}
```

[image]

1. **The JET color scheme didn't change with respect to the z-axis** as HUE scheme in the left? I think that it will be a problem when I add a color bar.
2. How to rescale the colors of HUE? (The red color is very dominant for this figure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to part one of your question is that you must explicitly pass in the x, y, or z component to the `ColorFunction`as shown below:

```
Plot3D[Abs[E^(I (t/2 + x)) (Coth[t + x])], {x, -2, 2}, {t, -2, 2}, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, #[z]], 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 15, 
   PlotRange -> All] & /@ {Hue, JetCM}
```

[image: Plots without legends]

As you can see, `PlotLegends->Automatic` fails to produce a legend. Presumably, it only works for named [Color Schemes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ColorSchemes.html).

Since `PlotLegends->Automatic` fails, the answer to part two of your question is to create custom bar legends. One possible approach is shown below:

```
(*Read in the numerical data*)
Get["https://pastebin.com/raw/gN4wGqxe"]
plt = Plot3D[
   Abs[E^(I (t/2 + x)) (Coth[t + x])], {x, -2, 2}, {t, -2, 2}, 
   PlotPoints -> 15, PlotRange -> All];
pts = Join @@ Cases[Normal@plt, Line[x1__] :> x1, Infinity];
HueBL = BarLegend[{Hue, MinMax[pts]}, LegendFunction -> "Frame"];
JetCM = With[{colorlist = RGBColor @@@ jetColors}, 
   Blend[colorlist, #] &];
JetCMBL = 
  With[{colorlist = RGBColor @@@ jetColors}, 
   BarLegend[{((Blend[colorlist, Rescale[#, MinMax[pts]]] &)), 
     MinMax[pts]}, LegendFunction -> "Frame"]];
Legended[Plot3D[
    Abs[E^(I (t/2 + x)) (Coth[t + x])], {x, -2, 2}, {t, -2, 2}, 
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, #[[1]][z]], PlotPoints -> 15,
     PlotRange -> All], #[[2]]] & /@ {{Hue, HueBL}, {JetCM, JetCMBL}}
```

[image: Custom bar legends]