# Customizing Hue function

Tags: plotting, color

Can I approximating the following Tex style color function with `Hue` function(or other functions):

[image]

I tried to use Hue:

```
ParametricPlot[
 r {Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {r, 0, 1},
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, \[Theta], r}, Hue@Max[(1 - 2 r), 0]], Axes -> None]
```

But result is not what I want, notice that the color in the center is same as the outer ring:

[image]

This is because the color of `Hue[0]` is same as `Hue[1]`. This cause some problems to me, because I have some function value changed from 0 to 1 smoothly, I don't want same color in both side.

Comment: The TeX colorfunction looks a lot like the Matlab default 'Jet', which is implemented in the accepted answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64513/is-there-an-easy-way-to-use-matteo-niccolis-perceptual-color-maps-for-2d-plots/64514#64514)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Hue` uses the HSB color space which is a cylindrical transformation of the RGB color space. Like you say, this means that `Hue[0]` and `Hue[1]` are both red, which is why you get the same colors in the center and outer ring. You'll want to change your `ColorFunction` to go from about `Hue[0.7]` for blue in the outer ring to `Hue[0]` in the inner ring.

You can do `Table[Hue[h], {h, 0, 1, .05}]` to get an idea of the color space.

[image]

The current `ColorFunction` you're using looks like

```
Plot[Max[(1 - 2 r), 0], {r, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> Function[r, Hue[Max[(1 - 2 r), 0]]], PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]]
```

[image: Yours]

so the outer ring is `Hue[0]` which is red. You want something instead like

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{2 (r - .3 r), r < .5}, {.7, r >= .5}}], {r, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> Function[r, Hue[Piecewise[{{2 (r - .3 r), r < .5}, {.7, r >= .5}}]]], PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]]
```

so the outer ring is `Hue[0.7]`.

[image]

or in your code

```
ParametricPlot[r {Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]},{r, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, \[Theta], r}, Hue@Piecewise[{{2 (r - .3 r), r < .5}, {.7, r >= .5}}]], Axes -> None]
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are many pre-defined color gradients

```
ColorData["Gradients"]

(* {"AlpineColors", "Aquamarine", "ArmyColors", "AtlanticColors", \
"AuroraColors", "AvocadoColors", "BeachColors", "BlueGreenYellow", \
"BrassTones", "BrightBands", "BrownCyanTones", "CandyColors", "CherryTones", \
"CMYKColors", "CoffeeTones", "DarkBands", "DarkRainbow", "DarkTerrain", \
"DeepSeaColors", "FallColors", "FruitPunchColors", "FuchsiaTones", \
"GrayTones", "GrayYellowTones", "GreenBrownTerrain", "GreenPinkTones", \
"IslandColors", "LakeColors", "LightTemperatureMap", "LightTerrain", \
"MintColors", "NeonColors", "Pastel", "PearlColors", "PigeonTones", \
"PlumColors", "Rainbow", "RedBlueTones", "RedGreenSplit", "RoseColors", \
"RustTones", "SandyTerrain", "SiennaTones", "SolarColors", "SouthwestColors", \
"StarryNightColors", "SunsetColors", "TemperatureMap", "ThermometerColors", \
"ValentineTones", "WatermelonColors"} *)
```

Put some or all into a [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) so you can visually compare and select your preferred gradient.

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[r {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]},
  {θ, 0, 2 π}, {r, 0, 1},
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, θ, r},
    ColorData[color]@Max[(1 - 2 r), 0]], Axes -> None],
 {{color, "TemperatureMap"},
  {"DarkRainbow", "LightTemperatureMap", "Rainbow", "TemperatureMap", 
   "ThermometerColors"},
  ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

[image]