# Remove the extra white-space padding introduced by implicit use of Inset in GraphicsColumn

Tags: plotting, graphics, export

### Simple Context

This is a question about understanding how `Inset` really works and how `GraphicsColumn` and the like automatically calculate `pos`, `opos`, and `size` (and what those really mean) in `Inset[fig, pos, opos, size]`. Related posts that I have perused at (variable) length include

- [How to align coordinate systems of Inset and enclosing Graphics?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83636/29734)
- `Jens`'s answer to [Do I have to code each case of this Grid full of plots separately?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6882/29734)

I am still digesting the first, and the second doesn't solve the particular problem I am facing (although it is exceedingly useful).

### Greater Context

I have an established workflow that allows me to generate journal-ready figures with correct widths, correct font sizes, good quality, and small-enough file size. The journals in which I publish are usually two-column format, so I often have multiple figures that include (at least) two plots in a column format. An archetypical example is shown `Frame`d below on the right:

[image]

(By the way, the color function was adapted from the `seaborn` color schemes as worked out in the answers to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84877/29734).)

The workflow typically involves something like the following.

- Generate the figures using [`Jens`'s amazing `contourDensityPlot`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3196/29734). (This allows `Export`ing to pdf that eliminates the lines of the density plot mesh.)
- Set the correct `FontSize` and `ImageSize` so that the exported figure will match the font size and column width used in the journal, based on suggestions found in [`Szabolcs`'s $\LaTeX$ and Mathematica answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/750/29734). (This is a key point: re-sizing the compound figure later can be an issue, since the fonts in the figure should match the fonts in the paper.)
- Use a generalization of the automated `ImagePadding` from [`Szabolcs`'s answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4060/29734) to align the figures in a `GraphicsColumn`. Use `Epilog` in the `GraphicsColumn` to add the annotations $(a)$ and $(b)$. (This is important: I cannot use `Column` because this disallows `Epilog`.)
- *Manually* go into the automated `Inset`s that `GraphicsColumn` creates and hack the size so that the compound figure width matches the widths of the component figures. This step is to get rid of the extra white space (highlighted by including the `Frame`) as shown in the figure on the left above. (The main question posed in this post is about automating this step. I walk through an example below.)
- `Export` as pdf and include in a document type-setted in $\LaTeX$.

### (Somewhat Vague) Question

`Inset` sizing is mysterious to me, so I use `GraphicsColumn` to get the sizing about right and then, by trial and error, change the size until I get what I want. Based on the example below, **can someone explain why `GraphicsColumn` creates a `Graphics` object that has all of the extra white space, why my hack works, and how the fix can be automated?** This question will become less vague with a specific example:

### Example

We consider two plots:

```
p1 = Plot[Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 1, 0.5}]
  , Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {None, "y"}
  , BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 10}
  , ImageSize -> 255
  ]
p2 = ListPlot[Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 1, 0.25}]
  , Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", None}
  , BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 10}
  , ImageSize -> 255
  ]
```

The framed parts of these figures have the same implicit `AspectRatio`, but that will not be the case in general. In addition, due to the different `FrameLabel`s, the *actual* aspect ratios of the figures are necessarily different. Therefore, we need to add equal `ImagePadding`s to the two plots.  If we were to able to use `Column`, we could set just the left and right padding using the trick by `Szabolcs` and `Heike` mentioned above to automatically extract the padding:

```
padding[g_Graphics] := With[
 {im = Image[Show[g, LabelStyle -> White, Background -> White]]}
 , BorderDimensions[im]
]
leftRightPadding[graphicsSequence__Graphics] := {
  1 + Max /@ Transpose@(First /@ #) & @ (padding /@ List@graphicsSequence)
  , {Automatic, Automatic}
}

ipLR = leftRightPadding[p1, p2]
(* {{36, 4}, {Automatic, Automatic}} *)
```

Then, we can make perfectly sized and spaced image using `Column` that can be directly exported:

```
Column[Show[#, ImagePadding -> ipLR] & /@ {p1, p2}]
Export["fig1.pdf", %]
```

resulting in (this is actually exported as a png)

[image]

which will be the perfect size for including in a $\LaTeX$ document. Unfortunately, I cannot use `Epilog` to add figure labels (a) and (b). So we use `GraphicsColumn` instead, but in order to line up the frame correctly, we need to have equal padding *on all sides* (which is something I don't understand). Therefore we use

```
maxPadding[graphicsSequence__Graphics] := 1 + {
  Max /@ Transpose@(First /@ #)
  , Max /@ Transpose@(Last /@ #)
 } & @ (padding /@ List @ graphicsSequence)

ip = maxPadding[p1, p2]
(* {{36, 4}, {37, 1}} *)
```

and generate the figure using

```
GraphicsColumn[Show[#, ImagePadding -> ip] & /@ {p1, p2}
 , ImageSize -> 255
 , Frame -> True]
Export["fig2.pdf", Show[%, ImageSize -> 255]]
```

resulting in

[image]

Normally I would not include the `Frame -> True`, but I have included it here to show the extra white space to the left and right (and usually top and bottom) of the figures.

At this point, to get rid of the extra white space, I play around with the `Inset` parameters until I hit upon something that works. Here, I did:

```
GraphicsColumn[Show[#, ImagePadding -> ip] & /@ {p1, p2}
 , ImageSize -> 255
 , Spacings -> 17
 , Frame -> True
] /. {Inset[a__, size_] :> Inset[a, {1.12, 1.33} size]}
```

I found the scale factors `1.12` and `1.33` that modify the quantities in `size` by trial and error. In addition, I need to set the `Spacings` by hand, which introduces another bottleneck to workflow. Finally, I will need to modify these so that there actually *is* a little white-space to the left for the `Epilog -> {Text["(a)", posA], Text["(b)", posB]}`.

Despite these annoyances, the hack works. Below, I am showing an `Export`ed `Row` of the `Column` solution and the hacked `GraphicsColumn` solution side-by-side. They are almost indistinguishable.

[image]

So, the question is, **what have I done?** I have very little idea how this works, and ideally there would be a solution that allows me to automate the process. (By the way, another option is to export the final figure with an image size *larger* than the column width and then clip the figure when I `\includegraphics` in the $\LaTeX$ document; this is obviously another non-ideal trial-and-error solution.)

### Some extra poking around

Just to show that something strange (to me) is going on, below are some screen shots of the combined figures with the component figures *selected*. First, the `Column` solution with the second figure selected:

[image]

Second, the non-hacked `GraphicsColumn` solution with second figure selected:

[image]

You can see how the border of the selection is *wider* and *taller* (barely) in the second, even though both versions have the *same* left-right `ImagePadding`. (I have played around with this more, including making the `ImagePadding` the same around the entire figure for the `Column` solution; the same sorts of thing happen.) Third, the final side-by-side figure with the second figure in the `GraphicColumn` solution selected:

[image]

You can see how the border of the selection is now right up against the left and right sides of the figure.

Finally, just for fun, note that if we give the same padding to the figures *only* on the right and left, then `GraphicsColumn` doesn't even line up the frames correctly. Calling

```
GraphicsColumn[Show[#, ImagePadding -> ipLR] & /@ {p1, p2},  ImageSize -> 255]
```

results in

[image]

This is the final mystery, I guess. Thank you for slogging through this long tale.

Comment: I have attacked this problem many times and prefer to generate my own `Graphics[{Inset[...],Inset[...],...}]` with appropriate options. See if this helps you: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79773/26956 (specifically, my function `undistortedGraphicsColumn`, easily generalizable to `GraphicsGrid` functionality).

Comment: The source of this behavior is that `GraphicsColumn` and co. allocate equal space to every enclosed `Graphics`, whereas `Column` stacks them as densely as possible. Additional conflict between e.g. the aspect ratio of the plots and the aspect ratio of the entire `GraphicsColumn` can cause further frustration (excessive white-space)

Comment: @LLlAMnYP. Thanks for the link. I didn't come across that one in my searches for some reason. I'll give it a look. (I figured that somehow this was a duplicate but couldn't find the specific solution.)

Comment: @LLlAMnYP. Your function `undistortedGraphicsColumn` works great, and your explanation in that post seems to identify the problem (I feel like I should've noticed that `GraphicsColumn` lazily chooses the `Frame` `AspectRatio` rather than the full `Graphics` aspect ratio, for instance). My question is definitely a duplicate, then. I'm inclined to close it, then, but link to your posted solution so that all of this will be easily searchable, since it's such a common problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I decided to modify [`undistortedGraphicsColumn` from `LLlAMnYP`'s post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79773/29734) to work for my purposes and extend it to an `undistortedGraphicsGrid`. Because I am particularly interested in aligning the plot region frames carefully, I have changed the names to `alignedGraphicsColumn` and `alignedGraphicsGrid`

Caveats, up front:

- `alignedGraphicsColumn` is a straight-forward extension of `undistortedGraphicsColumn`, but I feel like I've done *just* enough to warrant not closing the question as a duplicate and to supply my own answer.
- I've introduced some custom `Options`, but my implementation of them is messy and needs some work. Nonetheless, they are *somewhat* robust and allow control over the image size *after* the original plots have been made, which I think is pretty useful. Furthermore, there is some choice as to *how* the alignment should be done (at least for the `Column` version).
- I have implemented `Spacings` functionality, but there is no extensive testing of how well it works. It has worked on the simple cases that I tend to need.
- We can pass `Graphics` `Options` to the outer `Graphics` but not to the sub-plots that are `Inset` in the outer `Graphics`. This may or may not be useful.
- `alignedGraphicsGrid` is not very robust yet and really only works for plots whose plot regions have the same `AspectRatio` and whose image widths are all the same. In addition, sometimes the plots will be cut off, and I need to manually add some `ImagePadding` to the entire figure. I plan on extending it to include cases where each column can have a different width and each row can have a different width, but by then I'm encroaching on [`SciDraw`](http://scidraw.nd.edu/) territory, and I may as well just use that instead.

The code is included at the bottom of each section below.

For testing, let's use the plots

```
p1 = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}
   , Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {None, "left"}
   , BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 10}
   , ImageSize -> 300
   ];
p2 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}
   , Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{None, "right"}, {"bottom", None}}
   , BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 10}
   , ImageSize -> 255 , AspectRatio -> 1
   ];
p3 = Plot[(x - 1)^3, {x, 0, 1}
   , Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"bottom", None}
   , BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 10}
   , ImageSize -> 255
   ];
```

### alignedGraphicsColumn

#### Options

- Accepts `Graphics` options for the whole image.
- In the current implementation, `ImageSize` is broken, but it's functionality is mimicked with:
- `SubImageWidth`: an option that determines the figure width.

  - Choosing a positive real number `x` mimics the behavior of `ImageSize -> x`.
  - `Full` scales all of the sub-plots so that they all have the width of the sub-plot with the largest width, and the `ImageSize` is then this width.
  - `Automatic` is the default: the `ImageSize` is the width of the sub-plot with the largest width.
- `FrameAligned` determines the alignment functionality.

  - `All`: all plots get the same `ImagePadding`, and so the plots get lined up nicely, with lots of space between them, which can be fixed with `Spacings`.
  - `LeftOnly`: all plots get the same `ImagePadding` on the left and the right, which aligns the *left* sides of the frames only, unless all sub-plots have the same `ImageSize`.
  - `None`: applies no `ImagePadding`, so the plots do not line up.
- `Spacings`: works as advertised in `GraphicsGrid` and related functions.

#### Examples

Consider the function calls below

```
alignedGraphicsColumn[{p1, p2, p3}
 , FrameAligned -> All , SubImageWidth -> 200
 , Spacings -> 20, Background -> LightBlue]
alignedGraphicsColumn[{p1, p2, p3}
 , FrameAligned -> LeftOnly, SubImageWidth -> Automatic
 , Spacings -> 20]
alignedGraphicsColumn[{p1, p2, p3}
 , FrameAligned -> LeftOnly, SubImageWidth -> Full]
alignedGraphicsColumn[{p1, p2, p3}, FrameAligned -> None]
```

that result in the sequence of column figures below, respectively. For clarity, all of the figures have been wrapped in `Framed[]`.

- In the first, all of the sub-figures are lined up nicely, the width of the figure is `200`, I have added vertical spacings of `20` between the sub-figures, and we have added a `LightBlue` `Background` to the entire figure.
- In the second, the figures aren't all right-aligned because the first figure has a larger horizontal size than the others, and we have `FrameAligned -> LeftOnly`; `SubImageWidth -> Automatic` means that the width of the image will be the width of the largest sub-figures, but the sub-figures don't get their widths modified.
- In the third, `SubImageWidth -> Full` makes it so that all sub-figures have the same width (equal to the width of the largest sub-figures). `FrameAligned -> LeftOnly` automatically aligns the right-hand sides in this case (a consequence of the widths of the figures being equal).
- Finally, in the fourth, `FrameAligned -> None` means no extra padding is added to the figures, so their frames aren't lined up. There's no extraneous white space, though.

[image]

#### Code

The code requires the padding functions in the question above, included here for completeness:

```
padding[g_Graphics] := With[
 {im = Image[Show[g, LabelStyle -> White, Background -> White]]}
 , BorderDimensions[im]
]
leftRightPadding[graphicsSequence__Graphics] := {
  1 + Max /@ Transpose@(First /@ #) & @ (padding /@ List@graphicsSequence)
  , {Automatic, Automatic}
}
maxPadding[graphicsSequence__Graphics] := 1 + {
  Max /@ Transpose@(First /@ #)
  , Max /@ Transpose@(Last /@ #)
 } & @ (padding /@ List @ graphicsSequence)

Clear[alignedGraphicsColumn]
Options[alignedGraphicsColumn] = Join[{Spacings -> 0, FrameAligned -> LeftOnly, SubImageWidth -> Automatic}, Options[Graphics]];
alignedGraphicsColumn::faligned = "Value of option FrameAligned is not All, None, or LeftRight.";
alignedGraphicsColumn::width = "Value of option SubImageWidth is not Full, Automatic, or a positive machine number.";

alignedGraphicsColumn[list_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{sizes, width, plots, optWidth = OptionValue[SubImageWidth]}
  , Which[
      And[optWidth =!= Automatic, optWidth =!= Full, ! NumericQ@optWidth]
      , Return[Message[alignedGraphicsColumn::width]]
      , optWidth === Automatic, plots = list
      , optWidth === Full
      , plots = Show[#, ImageSize -> Max@First@(ImageDimensions /@ list)] & /@ list
      , NumericQ@optWidth
      , Which[! Element[optWidth, Reals], Return[Message[alignedGraphicsColumn::width]]
      , optWidth <= 0, Return[Message[alignedGraphicsColumn::width]]
      , optWidth > 0, plots = Show[#, ImageSize -> optWidth] & /@ list]
      , True
      , plots = list
    ]
  ; Which[And @@ (OptionValue[FrameAligned] =!= # & /@ {LeftOnly, All, None})
      , Return[Message[alignedGraphicsColumn::faligned]]
      , OptionValue[FrameAligned] === LeftOnly
      , plots = Show[#, ImagePadding -> leftRightPadding @@ plots] & /@ plots
      , OptionValue[FrameAligned] === All
      , plots = Show[#, ImagePadding -> maxPadding @@ plots] & /@ plots
      , OptionValue[FrameAligned] === None
      , True
    ]
  ; sizes = ImageDimensions /@ plots
  ; width = Max@sizes[[All, 1]]
  ; sizes = sizes[[All, 2]] + Join[{0}, ConstantArray[OptionValue[Spacings], Length@plots - 1]]
  ; Graphics[
      Table[
        Inset[plots[[i]], {0, -Plus @@ sizes[[;; i]]}, ImageScaled[{0, 0}]]
        , {i, Length[plots]}
      ]
      , ImageSize -> {width, Plus @@ sizes}
      , ImagePadding -> None
      , PlotRange -> {{0, width}, {-Plus @@ sizes, 0}}
      , AspectRatio -> Plus @@ sizes/width
      , PlotRangePadding -> None
      , FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graphics]]
    ]
 ]
```

### alignedGraphicsGrid

Since this one is not very robust yet, I'll just leave an example along with the code. There are lots of things which are pretty inelegant, so...

#### Example

This code:

```
alignedGraphicsGrid[{{p1, p1}, {p1, p1}, {p1, p1}} /. HoldPattern[FrameLabel -> _] :> Sequence[]
  , Spacings -> {-22, -20}, ImageWidth -> 400]
```

leads to this figure:

[image]

#### Code

```
Clear[alignedGraphicsGrid]
Options[alignedGraphicsGrid] =  Join[{Spacings -> 0, ImageWidth -> Automatic}, Options[Graphics]];
alignedGraphicsGrid::width = "Value of option ImageWidth is not Automatic or a positive machine number.";

alignedGraphicsGrid[list_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
  {size, sizes, width, height, plots, space = OptionValue[Spacings], optWidth = OptionValue[ImageWidth]}
  , plots = Map[Show[#, ImagePadding -> maxPadding @@ Flatten@list] &, list, {2}]
  ; size = ImageDimensions@plots[[1, 1]]
  ; sizes = space {Range[0, Last@#] /. {a___, b_, c_} :> {a, b, b}, Range[0, First@#]} + size {Range[0, Last@#], Range[1 + First@#]} & @Dimensions@plots
  ; Which[
     And[optWidth =!= Automatic, ! NumericQ@optWidth]
     , Return[Message[alignedGraphicsGrid::width]]
     , NumericQ @ optWidth
     , plots = Map[Show[#, ImageSize -> optWidth/sizes[[1, -1]] ImageDimensions[#][[1]]] &, plots, {2}]; sizes = sizes*optWidth/sizes[[1, -1]]
     , optWidth === Automatic
     , plots = list
    ]
  ; height = sizes[[2, -2]]; width = sizes[[1, -1]]
  ; Graphics[
     MapThread[
      Inset[#1, #2, ImageScaled[{0, 0}]] &
      , {plots, Transpose@Outer[List, sizes[[1, ;; -2]], -sizes[[2, ;; -2]]]}
      , 2
     ]
     , ImageSize -> {sizes[[1, -1]], height}
     , ImagePadding -> None
     , PlotRange -> {{0, width}, {-height, 0}}
     , AspectRatio -> height/width
     , PlotRangePadding -> None
     , FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graphics]]
    ]
 ]
```

Comment: `alignedGraphicsColumn' does a great job of formatting plots for publication. Thanks! When I use it, "FrameStyle" causes the frame labels to be clipped. How do you change the frame color, thickness when you use this?

Comment: @axsvl77. I never do. This code is likely not very robust to those kinds of changes, since I didn't plan for them. I actually have some ideas as to how to make it better, but I don't really have the time to work on it right now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am late to this party, but you could use PlotRangePadding->None

Comment: Can you expand on your answer with an example solving the problem outlined by the original question?