# Plot with two scales for X axis

Tags: plotting

I want to do something similar to [1 Plot, 2 Scale/Axis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/627/42847) but for the **X-axis**.

The aim is to have physical units below, but array indices at the top for easy access to the discrete data range.

So far I tried:

```
XY = Table[{i, Sin[i]}, {i, -10, 10, 0.5}];

DoubleXAxisPlotExample[XY : {{_?NumberQ, _?NumberQ} ..}] :=
  Overlay[{
    ListLinePlot[XY,
     ImagePadding -> 25,
     Frame -> True,
     FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {All, None}},
     PlotRange -> All],
    ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Range[Length[XY]], Part[XY, All, 2]}],
     ImagePadding -> 25,
     Frame -> True,
     FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {None, All}},
     PlotRange -> All]
    }];
```

`DoubleXAxisPlotExample@XY` returns:

[image]

However, with:

```
XY = Table[{i, 100000*Sin[i]}, {i, -10, 10, 0.5}];
```

`DoubleXAxisPlotExample@XY` returns:

[image]

**-> the left ticks have been truncated**

I understand that `ImagePadding -> 25` is there to let enough arbitrary space on the left, however in my code this is a fixed absolute value. To solve the problem, I think that this value should be computed according to the actual plot Y-range, but I do not know how to do that.

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use my function [`GraphicsInformation`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/45431) to obtain this information *(I think `GraphicsInformation` is more reliable than [`Image`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image) + [`BorderDimensions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BorderDimensions))*. Install the paclet/function:

```
PacletInstall[
    "GraphicsInformation",
    "Site"->"http://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlwoll/GraphicsInformation/master"
];
```

Then, load it:

```
<<GraphicsInformation`
```

For your example:

```
plots = {
    ListLinePlot[
        XY,
        Frame -> True,
        FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {All, None}},
        PlotRange -> All
    ],
    ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Range[Length[XY]], Part[XY, All, 2]}],
        Frame -> True,
        FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {None, All}},
        PlotRange -> All
    ]
};
padding = "ImagePadding" /. GraphicsInformation[plots]
```

> {{{44., 1.5}, {17., 0.5}}, {{44., 1.5}, {1.5, 16.}}}

This gives the actual [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding) used in the two plots. You can use [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread) to come up with the total [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding) that is needed:

```
MapThread[Max, padding, 2]
```

> {{44., 1.5}, {17., 16.}}

I will leave it to you to include `GraphicsInformation` in your `DoubleXAxisPlotExample` function.

Comment: Thanks for this! Happy to see that I was not the only one to have problems with image padding! :)

Answer (score 1):

One can automate the image padding with a hack described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4060/29734) and built upon
[here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88533/29734).

Define two padding functions

```
padding[g_Graphics] := With[{im = Image[Show[g, LabelStyle -> White, Background -> White]]}, BorderDimensions[im]]
maxPadding[graphicsSequence__Graphics] := 1 + {Max /@ Transpose@(First /@ #), Max /@ Transpose@(Last /@ #)} &@(padding /@ List@graphicsSequence)
```

Then,

```
DoubleXAxisPlotExample[XY : {{_?NumberQ, _?NumberQ} ..}] := Module[{plt1, plt2, pad},
  plt1 = ListLinePlot[XY,
    PlotRange -> All,
    Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {All, None}}];
  plt2 = ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Range[Length[XY]], Part[XY, All, 2]}],
    PlotRange -> All,
    Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {None, All}}];
  pad = maxPadding[plt1, plt2];
  plt = Overlay[{
     Show[plt1, ImagePadding -> pad],
     Show[plt2, ImagePadding -> pad]
     }]
 ]
```

Then:

```
XY = Table[{i, 100000*Sin[i]}, {i, -10, 10, 0.5}];
DoubleXAxisPlotExample@XY
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for the hack (I was not aware of these links, sorry for the duplicate!).