# Replicate effect of FrameTicks->All manually

Tags: plotting

I need a way to get the absolute tick specifications in the form of list of position/label pairs, and have not been able to come up with a robust way.

For the following, I'll be using this test plot:

```
plt = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Things I have tried so far include:

- Specifying `` Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity,Identity}] ``:

  [image: Mathematica graphics]

  Notice the missing `1.0` tick mark.
- Using `AbsoluteOptions`:

  ```
  InputForm@PlotRange /. Quiet@AbsoluteOptions@plt
  (* {{0., 1.}, {0., 0.9999999795918367}} *)
  ```

  This probably also explains why the above fails.
- `PlotRange@plt`, `` Charting`CommonDump`getplotrange@plt `` and [`GraphicsInformation@plt`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161957/36508) all fail similarly
- `FullGraphics` [is also completely broken](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83648/is-fullgraphics-an-abandoned-function-is-there-an-alternative)
- I tried to look at the `GraphicsBox` expression resulting from the plot, but the `PlotRange` is still wrong there and the `FrameTicks` have not yet been expanded.
- I also tried to look at the definitions of `` Typeset`MakeBoxes ``, which appears to handle some of the option transformations for graphics, but I couldn't find anything, and they also seem to be unused during normal operation

Is there any way to replicate what the front end is doing? I guess it's just rounding the plot ranges before feeding them into whatever tick-making function it uses internally, but is there a way to tell what exactly is going on?

Comment: Not sure what happened there, but try this: ``tt = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][0, 3]; {Plot[2 x, {x, 0, 3}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {None, {tt, None}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0], Plot[2 x, {x, 0, 3}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {None, {Automatic, None}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0]}``

Comment: @J.M. I'm aware that that will work - but I need a way to get the ticks for an arbitrary plot, where the plot range is not manually set to something nice. As I tried to explain in the question, the front-end seems to be doing some rounding, but if I want it to always work, I need to know what exactly is being done.

Comment: @LukasLang, just saw this question, maybe too late, but... You probably aware of `Charting`get2DPlotRange[Plot[...]]`, this gives true plot ranges used by MMA to plot and to place ticks. So for your `plt` it gives `{{0.,1.},{0.,1.}}`. Then `Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity,Identity}][<here is plot range>]` replicate MMA ticks.

Comment: @Alx Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately I can't seem to get it to work. If you look at ``Charting`get2DPlotRange@plt // InputForm``, $1$ is still excluded from the vertical plot range.

Comment: I tried this way: pr=Charting`get2DPlotRange[plt], then Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0, FrameTicks ->  Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][Sequence @@ pr[[2]]]] and all 1s are presented.

Comment: @LukasLang, some weird behavior of Charting`scaledTicks. As I wrote in previous comment, `FrameTicks` option with plot range from `get2DPlotRange` gives desired result, but the same Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity,Identity}][Sequence@@pr[[2]]] alone doesn't include 1. It is strange because underlying `N@FindDivisions[pr[[2]],{6,6}]` includes 1. And the full form Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear", {Identity, Identity}, "Nice"][Sequence @@ pr[[2]]] also shows 1.

Comment: @Alx Sorry for coming back to you so late - I think I finally figured out why your code is "working": The plot you show with the explicit ticks produces the correct result because `Plot` silently (for some reason) discards the invalid `FrameTicks` specification and uses the default. If you specify ``FrameTicks->{Automatic, Charting`ScaledTicks[…][…]}``, it gives the wrong result as expected. And for the other part: It looks like `FindDivisions` is not used for that particular `ScaledTicks` call, only for the `"Nice"` version, which probably explains why that one works

Comment: @LukasLang, well, you are right with your example of semi-Automatic `FrameTicks`. But this can be fixed either by removing `PlotRangePadding -> 0` option, or adding `PlotRange -> pr`, where `pr = Charting``get2DPlotRange[plt]`. This works for my needs (I use this when I need custom ticks), but I have no such experience in MMA as you have and this may work just by a fluke.