# How *does* Mathematica generate ticks and tick values?

Tags: plotting, ticks

This question has sort of been asked before in various guises (e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132568/extract-ticks-from-plot/) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2073/remove-tick-labels-but-retain-tick-marks-in-regionplot-and-related-functions)), but the answers given there do not answer the question I'm posing.

Before I pose my question, a definition. Let use the name 'ticks definition' for the following information: the locations of the minor ticks, the locations of the major ticks, which major ticks get a label, and which label they get. A ticks definition can be given as a list whose typical entry might look like this: `{-0.4, "-0.4", {0.01, 0}, {}}`. Each axis gets its own ticks definition. (The entries may also contain information about the lengths and widths of the tick marks, but let's ignore those.)

**Now I can pose my question:**

> In 2D plots generated by the `Plot` command with the default settings, what function does *Mathematica* use to generate the ticks definitions? The answer should ideally be a (presumably undocumented) *Mathematica* function resembling `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` (but that particular one doesn't actually produce the same ticks definitions as `Plot` does with default settings; see below). In other words, the answer should ideally be a function which, given only the *x*-range and *y*-range of the plot as inputs,<sup>1</sup> generates the same ticks definitions as the command `Plot` does by default. When I say 'generate', I mean that the output of such a function should be a list whose entries have the form I mentioned in the previous paragraph. For example, the undocumented function `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` produces a list whose typical entry looks like this: `{{-4., -4, {0.01, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}` This is of the right *form*. However, in the example below, the particular numerical values that `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` produces do not reproduce the default behavior of `Plot`.)
>
> <sup><sup>1</sup>The *x*-range and *y*-ranges of the plot can be generated through `PlotRange`, which is another undocumented function (though this apparently won't work if the plot has certain non-default features, such as a legend).</sup>
>
> If no one knows what this function is, also acceptable would be a function that produces such a string given the *entire plot* as input (like `AbsoluteOptions` does—unfortunately, that function does not work correctly in general, see below). In other words, also acceptable would be a function that 'extracts' the tick marks and tick labels from the plot. The question posed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132568/extract-ticks-from-plot/) asked for precisely such a function, but none of the answers given there actually work correctly (i.e. reproduce the default behavior of `Plot`), including the accepted one.

**The default behavior of `Plot` as far as the ticks is not reproduced by any function known to me**

One might think that the function I'm looking for would be one (or more) of the following: 1. the output of `AbsoluteOptions`, or 2. of the `LinTicks` function from [SciDraw](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/8958/), or 3. of the undocumented function `` Charting`FindTicks ``, or 4. of the undocumented function `` Charting`ScaledTicks ``. However, as will be seen, none of these can reproduce the default behavior reliably. True, for some special values of *x*-ranges and *y*-ranges, some of these functions may happen to reproduce the default behavior. However, in the specific example below, none of them do.

<sup>This of course presents a problem: even if a function is found that reproduces the default behavior in this particular case, how will we know that it would reproduce it in all cases? I suppose this can only be known by someone who actually has access to the source code for the relevant aspect of the `Plot` command. Nevertheless, if anyone has a guess as to which function is used by `Plot`, and that function indeed reproduces the default behavior in the example below, that would be of great interest.</sup>

**An MWE that shows that the default behavior of `Plot` is not reproduced by any of the four methods I mentioned**

Below, I give a MWE that shows that the default ticks definitions used by `Plot` are **not** reproduced via either 'extracting' them by using `AbsoluteOptions`, or via generating them by using any of the following functions: [SciDraw](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/8958/)'s function `LinTicks`, the undocumented function `` Charting`FindTicks ``, or the undocumented function `` Charting`ScaledTicks ``. Namely, I compare the plots in which the ticks were generated using

1. the default *Mathematica* settings;
2. `AbsoluteOptions`;
3. the `LinTicks` function from [SciDraw](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/8958/), with the ranges given implicitly (i.e. `Ticks -> {LinTicks, LinTicks}`);
4. as above, but with the ranges explicitly specified (i.e. `Ticks -> {LinTicks@@xPlotRange, LinTicks@@yPlotRange}`, where `{xPlotRange, yPlotRange} = PlotRange[plot]`);
5. the undocumented internal function `` Charting`FindTicks ``, with the ranges given implicitly;
6. as above, but with the ranges explicitly specified;
7. the undocumented internal function `` Charting`ScaledTicks ``, with the ranges given implicitly;
8. as above, but with the ranges explicitly specified;

The point is that none of the methods 2-8 replicate the default in 1 for *both* axes (see the plots at the end). Thus, *Mathematica* must be using some other undocumented function to generate the ticks definitions.

(An additional question is why it matters whether the ranges are given implicitly or explicitly, in other words, why 3 doesn't match 4, 5 doesn't match 6, and 7 doesn't match  8.)

I should emphasize that what I am really interested in is an 'explicit' method (like in 4, 6, and 8), which generates an explicit ticks definition (i.e. a list whose entries have a form such as `{-0.4, "-0.4", {0.01, 0}, {}}`).

Here is the MWE:

```
(* The default plot *)
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -0.5, Pi}, PlotLabel -> "Mathematica Default"]

(* Extract the plot ranges *)
{xPlotRange, yPlotRange} = PlotRange[plot];

(* Plot using AbsoluteOptions *)
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -0.5, Pi},  Ticks -> {AbsoluteOptions[plot, Ticks][[1, 2, 1]], 
AbsoluteOptions[plot, Ticks][[1, 2, 2]]}, PlotLabel -> "AbsoluteOptions"]

(* Plot using LinTicks with the ranges implicit *)
Plot[Sin[x], {x,-0.5, Pi}, Ticks -> {LinTicks, LinTicks}, PlotLabel -> "LinTicks implicit ranges"]

(* Plot using LinTicks with explicitly specifying the ranges *)
Plot[Sin[x], {x,-0.5, Pi}, Ticks -> {LinTicks@@xPlotRange, LinTicks@@yPlotRange}, PlotLabel -> "LinTicks explicit ranges"]

(* Plot using Charting`FindTicks with the ranges implicit *)
Plot[Sin[x], {x,-0.5, Pi}, Ticks -> {Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}], 
Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}]}, PlotLabel -> "Charting`FindTicks implicit ranges"]

(* Plot using Charting`FindTicks with explicitly specifying the ranges *)
Plot[Sin[x], {x,-0.5, Pi}, Ticks -> {Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}]@@xPlotRange, 
Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}]@@yPlotRange}, PlotLabel -> "Charting`FindTicks explicit ranges"]

(* Plot using Charting`ScaledTicks with the ranges implicit *)
Plot[Sin[x], {x,-0.5, Pi}, Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}], 
Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}]}, PlotLabel -> "Charting`ScaledTicks implicit ranges"]

(* Plot using Charting`ScaledTicks with explicitly specifying the ranges *)
Plot[Sin[x], {x,-0.5, Pi}, 
Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}]@@xPlotRange, 
Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}]@@yPlotRange}, 
PlotLabel -> "Charting`ScaledTicks explicit ranges"]
```

Here are the plots that the MWE produces in *Mathematica* 11.3.0.0 running on 64-bit Linux (kubuntu 20.04):

[image]

Again, none of the methods are successful in replicating the default behavior for *both* axes. Indeed, not a single 'explicit' method (which is what I'm after) reproduces the default behavior for the *y*-axis.

Comment: It is little bit hard to comprehend the whole post. What is your *real* problem?

Comment: @yarchik The background is that I am making a wrapper for `Plot` which will 'LaTeXify' the tick labels: it will replace the tick labels by the outputs of `MaTeX`. This is for font consistency with the LaTeX document into which the plot will ultimately go.

Comment: @yarchik If I decide to use e.g. SciDraw's `LinTick` to generate the tick definitions (by 'tick definitions' I mean the locations of the minor and major ticks, and which major ticks get a label, and which label), I know what to do. Namely, I have a 'LaTeXifying' function that takes the output of `LinTick`, which is a list of entries such as `{-0.4, "-0.4", {0.01, 0}, {}}`, and replaces the second subentry by the output of `MaTeX["-0.4"]`; note that the Head of that output is Graphics.

Comment: @yarchik This works. Instead of `LinTick`, I could just as well use the output of ``Charting`FindTicks`` or of ``Charting`ScaledTicks``. I could even generate a preliminary plot, 'extract' the ticks by applying `AbsoluteOptions`, and again apply the same 'LaTeXifying' function.  My **problem** is that 1. none of these in general give the same tick definitions as the default output of `Plot`, but 2. it is often the the latter that look the best. So I would like to have access to the tick definitions that `Plot` makes, so I could 'LaTeXify' those.

Comment: @yarchik As an aside: the question of how *Mathematica* generates tick definitions seems of independent fundamental interest. The point of my question is that *Mathematica* doesn't use any of the functions you'd *think* it would use, and even the 'extraction' using `AbsoluteOptions` gives a wrong output in general.

Comment: Not all internal and undocumented functions are available at top level. Any function implemented in the underlying C code would be completely unreachable from top level.  I don't know for a fact that `Plot` makes its ticks in C code, but it wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: Generally the automatic setting for ticks is generated by the frontend in C++ code.  Something like ``Charting`FindTicks`` is your best, easiest approximation to that.  There are cases where it will differ, but not in a way that I would consider the ticks to be "wrong" for the plot.

Comment: @BrettChampion Why does `AbsoluteOptions` fail? Alternatively, what is the output of it? It's neither what `Plot` gives by default nor what  ``Charting`FindTicks`` or ``Charting`ScaledTicks`` give.

Comment: @linguisticturn - see the comments to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97317/9490)

Comment: @JasonB I see… Thanks!

Comment: @BrettChampion It would be quite useful to have a single canonical function that generates the ticks, and which is exposed to users. Quality tick and tick label generation is far from easy (there are fine details like whether to include decimal points or not), so people shouldn't have to try to emulate the FE's behaviour, as it will never be perfect. Even built-ins which generate their own ticks tend to produce slightly inconsistent results, which don't quite match with what the FE does. So I'd assume that WRI developers would also benefit from a canonical tick generation functions.

Comment: @BrettChampion Or is there a reason why it's necessary for ticks to be generated by the FE? I understand that to determine the image padding, it is necessary to know the current font and glyph sizes. That can only be done by the FE. But tick generation does not take such FE-only information into account, does it?

Comment: As a sidenote: As far as I can tell, custom ticks specifications cannot even reproduce the length of the default ticks (custom tick lengths are always scaled by the plot size, whereas the default ticks are not). As for the problem at hand: have you tried exporting the plot to PDF and importig it again? You could probably extract the exact tick specification that way, but as mentioned, you'll run into issues with the tick length

Comment: Also: [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/169249/replicate-effect-of-frameticks-all-manually) is a highly related (if not duplicate) question (sadly also without answer)

Comment: @LukasLang Thank you for the comment, and for alerting me to your related question! Your pdf suggestion may indeed work for most plots, depending on how consistent the structure of the imported graphics is. I had been working on extracting the tick labels via `Rasterize` and `TextRecognize` from a plot that is first modified so that pretty much only the labels are visible and so that they are made larger (the latter can be done inside `Show`). This will give me the labels, and the analysis of the pdf, with a little luck, should give the tick locations. Then we can worry about the tick sizes!