# Padding in an inset object

Tags: padding, inset

I have seen something similar asked in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88312/remove-the-extra-white-space-padding-introduced-by-implicit-use-of-inset-in-grap), but wasn't able to adapt it. I've been using [Jens's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/245/jens) code for scaled inset graphics:

```
stretchText[char_, pos_, scale_, angle_: 0] := Module[{g, coords, xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax}, g = First@
First@ImportString[ExportString[char, "PDF"], 
  "TextOutlines" -> True];coords = Apply[Join, 
Cases[g, FilledCurve[___, p_] :> Flatten[p, 1], Infinity]];{{xMin, xMax}, {yMin, yMax}} = Map[{Min[#], Max[#]} &[#] &, Transpose[coords]];Rotate[Inset[Graphics[g, PlotRange -> {{xMin, xMax}, {yMin, yMax}}, If[ListQ[scale], AspectRatio -> Full, AspectRatio -> Automatic]],pos, {xMin, yMin}, scale], angle]]
```

which works beautifully, but has some strange padding properties. When I run

```
Graphics[stretchText["︷", {0, -20}, {350, 30}]]
```

The output is padded heavily to the left.

[image]

Can anyone suggest how to remove this padding? I am combining many of these graphics objects of different sizes and positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `PlotRange`

```
Graphics[stretchText["︷", {0, -20}, {350, 30}], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 350}, {-20, 10}}]
```

Comment: Well, that's a little embarrassing :-) thanks!

Comment: It wasn't immediately obvious.